# Why can't the default constructor be called with empty brackets?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, c++-faq, most-vexing-parse

Is there any good reason that an empty set of round brackets (parentheses) isn't valid for calling the default constructor in C++?

```
MyObject  object;  // ok - default ctor
MyObject  object(blah); // ok

MyObject  object();  // error
```

I seem to type "()" automatically everytime. Is there a good reason this isn't allowed?

Comment: Someone should come up with a better title for this, but I can't think of what that would be.  At least spell out "constructor" to help the search engine(s).

Comment: And this is just another good example where C++ is context sensitive. The example code in the question would also fail if `blah` would be a class.

Comment: One thing that I noticed is that if I only have the default constructor then the compiler doesn't give any error if I use `()` e.g. `MyObject object` works as usual & `MyObject object()` does not give any error! Could someone please explain why? I mean I haven't defined the function in my `main`... so it should give an error, right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 194, accepted):

**Most vexing parse**

This is related to what is known as "C++'s most vexing parse". Basically, anything that can be interpreted by the compiler as a function declaration will be interpreted as a function declaration.

Another instance of the same problem:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.txt");
std::vector<T> v(std::istream_iterator<T>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<T>());
```

`v` is interpreted as a declaration of function with 2 parameters.

The workaround is to add another pair of parentheses:

```
std::vector<T> v((std::istream_iterator<T>(ifs)), std::istream_iterator<T>());
```

Or, if you have C++11 and list-initialization (also known as uniform initialization) available:

```
std::vector<T> v{std::istream_iterator<T>{ifs}, std::istream_iterator<T>{}};
```

With this, there is no way it could be interpreted as a function declaration.

Comment: I had read Effective STL but I didn't remember seeing that. i will have to read it again, thanks

Comment: Nitpick: you _can_ declare functions inside functions. It's called _local functions_ in C, and at least `extern "C" foo();`-style is also allowed in C++.

Comment: Thanks, mmutz, don't know what i was thinking when i wrote it, probably confused declaration with definition. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: How can that be interpreted as a function?

Comment: @Casebash, `std::vector` is return type; `v` is function name; `(` opens formal argument list; `std::istream_iterator` is type of first argument; `ifs` is name of first argument, `()` around `ifs` are effectively ignored; second `std::istream_iterator` is type of second argument, which is unnamed, `()` around it are also ignored; ');' closes argument list and function declaration.

Comment: There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression-statement with a function-style explicit type conversion as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. In those cases the statement is a
declaration. (C++ ISO/IEC (2003) 6.8.1)

Comment: @Constantin, the parentheses after the second argument are not ignored. The second parameter is not a `std::istream_iterator` but a pointer/reference to a function that takes no arguments and returns an `istream_iterator`.

Comment: This "feature" lets you declare functions without #including the function's header file. Yes, simple text inclusion could still blow an Ancient C compiler's resource limits if the header was large/complex enough. Remember that there was only 1 namespace for functions (which `main`, the Standard library, your OS's library, 3rd-party code, and your code all shared) so there was no ambiguity where the function came from.

Comment: If it's not the *most* vexing parse, can we call it *a* vexing parse? It still is vexing, is it not?

Comment: Do you need `std::istream_iterator<T>{}` or is `std::istream_iterator<T>` sufficient?

Comment: @PostSelf `std::istream_iterator<T>` is type name, you can't pass type to function, but you can infer type and call it's default constructor with just `{}`

Answer (score 126):

Because it is treated as the declaration for a function:

```
int MyFunction(); // clearly a function
MyObject object(); // also a function declaration
```

Comment: But it should give an error, right? Because we haven't defined the `object()` function right? Could you please elaborate on that? I'm confused right now. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: On a side note, in my `main`, I even tried these: `any_variable_name random_function_name()` e.g. `int func1()` , `double func2()`, `void func3()`, etc. and all of them works i.e. my program gets compiled without any error! However, I haven't defined any of those functions, so, I should get errors, right?

Comment: @Milan I would expect linker errors if you actually tried to call those functions. Otherwise they are just declarations

Answer (score 52):

The same syntax is used for function declaration - e.g. the function `object`, taking no parameters and returning `MyObject`

Comment: Thanks - it wouldn't occur to me to declare a function in th emiddle of some other code. But I suppose it is legal.

Answer (score 11):

Because the compiler thinks it is a declaration of a function that takes no arguments and returns a MyObject instance.

Answer (score 7):

I guess, the compiler would not know if this statement:

> MyObject object();

is a constructor call or a function prototype declaring a function named *object* with return type *MyObject* and no  parameters.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use the more verbose way of construction:

```
MyObject object1 = MyObject();
MyObject object2 = MyObject(object1);
```

In C++0x this also allows for `auto`:

```
auto object1 = MyObject();
auto object2 = MyObject(object1);
```

Comment: This requires a copy constructor and is inefficient

Comment: @Casebash: The compiler is probably smart enough to use some `RVO`-like optimization prevent it from being inefficient.

Comment: "Probably" means "I am guessing". Regarding optimization people usually do not want to guess but rather take the explicit way.

Comment: @Stefan: You do not need to "guess"; copy elision will happen here in all mainstream compilers and that's been the case for well over a decade. Not that this is good code.

Comment: @Casebash since C++11 here will be used move assignment operator, which is faster for classes, holding resourses on heap.

Comment: Since C++17 there is no copy/move,  the behaviour is defined as identical to direct initialization

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned many times, it's a declaration.  It's that way for backward compatibility.  One of the many areas of C++ that are goofy/inconsistent/painful/bogus because of its legacy.

Answer (score 5):

From n4296 [dcl.init]:

> [ Note:
>  Since `()` is not permitted by the syntax for *initializer*, 
>   `X a();` is not the declaration of an *object* of class X, but the
>   declaration of a *function* taking no argument and returning an X. The
>   form () is permitted in certain other initialization contexts (5.3.4,
>   5.2.3, 12.6.2). 
>   
> —end note ]

[C++11 Link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init#10)
[C++14 Link](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init#11)

Comment: Can you add a link for the source?

Answer (score 3):

As the others said, it is a function declaration. Since C++11 you can use brace initialization if you need to see the empty *something* that explicitly tells you that a default constructor is used.

```
Jedi luke{}; //default constructor
```