# C++ Question about default constructor

Tags: c++, class

What does it mean to call a class like this:

```
class Example
{
 public: 
  Example(void);
  ~Example(void);
}

int main(void)
{
 Example ex(); // <<<<<< what is it called to call it like this?

 return(0);
}
```

Like it appears that it isn't calling the default constructor in that case. Can someone give a reason why that would be bad?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: Exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/ctor-with-no-arguments

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently you are trying to call the default constructor like so.

```
Example ex();
```

This is not actually calling the default constructor.  Instead you are defining a function prototype with return type Example and taking no parameters.  In order to call the default constructor, omit the ()'s

```
Example ex;
```

Comment: Not a function pointer (that would be `Example (*ex)()`) but a function prototype.

Answer (score 8):

This declares a function prototype for a function named `ex`, returning an `Example`! You are *not* declaring and initializing a variable here.

Answer (score 4):

Does it even compile? Anyway, see [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/ctor-with-no-arguments).

Comment: Related?  I'd call it a duplicate, myself.

Answer (score 2):

As has been noted `Example ex();` declares a function prototype.  Not what anyone would expect.  This C++ wart will be fixed by the new C++0x standard.  In the future the preferred syntax will be `Example ex{};`.  The new uniform construction has many other nice features, see more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Uniform_initialization).