# Why is there no call to the constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, most-vexing-parse

This code doesn't behave how I expect it to.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Class
{
    Class()
    {
        cout<<"default constructor called";
    }

    ~Class()
    {
        cout<<"destrutor called";
    }
};

int main()
{    
    Class object();
}
```

I expected the output 'default constructor called', but I did not see anything as the output. What is the problem?

Comment: @dribeas: This isn't really the most vexing parse; it's just a slightly vexing parse. The "most vexing parse" is usually reserved for an attempt to create a variable with a direct-initializer of a value-initialized temporary: `A a(A());` (My mistake originally.)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Answer (score 34):

Nope. Your line `Class object();` Declared a function. What you want to write is `Class object;`

Try it out.

You may also be interested in the most vexing parse (as others have noted). A great example is in [Effective STL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) Item 6 on page 33. (In 12th printing, September 2009.) Specifically the example at the top of page 35 is what you did, and it explains why the parser handles it as a function declaration.

Comment: +1, btw Visual C++ issues `warning C4930: prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)` in such cases.

Comment: Is that really the "most vexing parse," though?  I always thought the phrase referred to the more frustrating problem, that `T x(T())` is a function declaration.

Comment: @James McNellis: That's what Scott Meyers called it. I don't exactly agree, and I didn't even connect this question with it immediately. I think your example is much more common and frustrating.

Answer (score 18):

> No call to constructor

Because the constructor never gets called actually.

`Class object();` is interpreted as the declaration of a function `object` taking no argument and returning an object of `Class` [by value]

Try `Class object;`

**EDIT**:

As Mike noticed this is not exactly the same code as what you are feeding to the compiler. Is the constructor/destructor `public` or is `Class` a struct?

However google for C++ most vexing parse.

Comment: Got to the answer a moment before me _and_ reformatted the post. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
Class obj;
//or
Class *obj = new Class(/*constructor arguments*/);
```