# Difference between creating object with () or without

Tags: c++, qt, most-vexing-parse

i just run into the problem

```
error: request for member ‘show’ in ‘myWindow’, which is of non-class type ‘MainGUIWindow()’
```

when trying to compile a simple qt-application:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "gui/MainGUIWindow.h"


int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  QApplication app( argc, argv );


  MainGUIWindow myWindow();
  myWindow.show();


  return app.exec();
}
```

I solved this by replacing

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow();
```

by

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow;
```

but I don't understand the difference. My question: What is the difference?

Regards,
Dirk

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Comment: @FredOverflow This is not a duplicate of that issue, the case with new is different as Amen below has pointed out. I don't know if there is another issue somewhere it may be a duplicate of.

Comment: before anyone else gets the wrong idea, this is *not* a duplicate. The titles are similar, but the questions are entirely different. One is about the different initalization rules in C++, the other is about why code intended to instantiate an object is instead parsed as a function declaration.

Comment: Actually, __this is a dupe__ of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Comment: Better duplicate because this more closely matches this question: [Is no parentheses on a C++ constructor with no arguments a language standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-c-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard). This isn't really the most vexing parse, it's just a slightly vexing parse.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Why is there no call to the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor) .

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The other answers correctly state that the parentheses version is actually a function declaration. To understand it intuitively, suppose you wrote `MainGUIWindow f();` Looks more like a function,  doesn't it? :)
The more interesting question is what is the difference between

```
MainGUIWindow* p = new MainGUIWindow;
```

and

```
MainGUIWindow* p = new MainGUIWindow();
```

The version with parentheses is called value-initialization, whereas the version without is called default-initialization. For non-POD classes there is no difference between the two. For POD-structs, however, value-initialization involves setting all members to 0,

my2c

Addition: In general, if some syntactic construct can be interpreted both as a declaration and something else, the compiler ***always resolves the ambiguity in favor of the declaration***.

Comment: This is called the "most vexing parse".

Comment: The more vexing parse comes when you try to create an instance of a class that takes one member and you pass in what you think is a temporary, especially a problem when it has an implicit constructor

Comment: Cong-rats and other rodents for crossing the 10k barrier, but this is a dupe. I suppose there's many "most vexing parse" questions out there. (I marked the first one that seemed a match.)

Answer (score 20):

The following:

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow();
```

declares a function that takes no arguments and returns `MainGUIWindow`. I.e. `myWindow` is a function name.

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow;
```

on the other hand creates an object `myWindow` of type `MainGUIWindow`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is, that

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow();
```

declares function `myWindow`, which takes no parameters and returns `MainGUIWindow`, whereas

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow;
```

creates new object of type `MainGUIWindow`, calling it's default constructor.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real problems with the situation you have described. You remove the parentheses and bingo! it works.

The "most vexing parse" is a much bigger issue when it takes a single parameter and you want to pass in a temporary, eg

```
class Foo
{
public:
 explicit Foo( const Bar& bar );
};

Foo foo( Bar() );
```

will not create an instance of a Foo but will also declare a function that takes a function-pointer, and this one really does often sting you.

Answer (score 3):

One of the guidelines for C++ compilers, in order to resolve code ambiguities, is: when something can be a function declaration, it is a function declaration. So when the compiler sees:

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow();
```

It understands you are declaring a function called `myWindow`, that takes no parameters and returns a `MainGUIWindow`. Obviously this is not what you want.

Just remove the parenthesis and you will be fine:

```
MainGUIWindow myWindow; // Create an object called myWindow, of type MainGUIWindow
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ every expression that looks like a function declaration is a declaration of a function. Consider more complex sample that in your question:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
  X( int value ) : x(value) {}
  int x;
};

struct Y
{
  Y( const X& x ) : y(x.x) {}
  int y;
};

int main()
{
  int test = 10;
  Y var( X(test) );                 // 1
  std::cout << var.y << std::endl;  // 2

  return 0;
}
```

At first glance (1) is a declaration of the local variable `var` which should be initialized with a temporary of a type `X`. But this looks like a function declaration for a compiler and you will get an error in (2):

```
 error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘var’, which is of non-class type ‘Y(X)’
```

The compiler considers that (1) is the function with name `var`:

```
Y                var(             X                     test            );
^- return value  ^-function name  ^-type of an argument ^-argument name
```

Now, how to say to the compiler that you do not want to declare a function? You could use additional parentheses as follows:

```
Y var( (X(test)) );
```

In your case `MainGUIWindow myWindow()` for the compiler looks like function declaration:

```
MainGUIWindow    myWindow(        void                  )
^- return value  ^-function name  ^-type of an argument
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, from CppCon 2017: Louis Brandy “Curiously Recurring C++ Bugs at Facebook”

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> (_mutex);
```

Is a declaration of a lock named "_mutex" that locks nothing. Since you typically don't need to interact with locks later, it's very easy to miss giving it a name.

This is a problem for any RAII object that has both a default constructor and a more useful constructor that takes one argument.