# error : expression must have class type

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the class in C++; it's written like this.

in second source,

```
void idealtype::compare(idealtype T1)
{
if (height.size() > T1.height.size())
    cout << T1.getname() << " " << T1.getage() << "\t" << T1.getheight() << "\n";
else if (height.size() < T1.height.size())
    cout << getname() << " " << getage() << "\t" << getheight() << "\n";
else if (height.size() == T1.height.size())
{
    cout << T1.getname() << " " << T1.getage() << "\t" << T1.getheight() << "\n";
    cout << getname() << " " << getage() << "\t" << getheight() << "\n";
}
cout << "\n";
}
```

in header;

```
class idealtype
{public:
void compare(idealtype);
```

....

```
private:
int height;
}
```

in main source;
....

```
idealtype A(a,b,c) // c is "height"
```

....

```
idealtype B(a,b,c) // c is "height"
B.compare(A)
```

I think it's all done well, but Visual keeps showing me,

(in second source, on every if() state) error : expression must have class type

So, what's the KEY of this problem?

Plz help me, guys :)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167555/visual-2010-keeps-telling-me-error-expression-must-have-class-type?rq=1

Comment: `height.size()` did you mean `sizeof(height)`?? I don't get what you want there, `height` is declared as `int` member.

Comment: `idealtype A(a,b,c)`: you're missing a `;` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, what's the KEY of this problem?

In your code you say

```
if (height.size() > T1.height.size())

class idealtype {
    // ...
private:
    int height; // <<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```

since `height` is declared as `int` it doesn't have any class like methods. That's why the compiler complains.