# Initialization of object with default constructor

Tags: c++, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)
>   [Difference between creating object with () or without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116541/difference-between-creating-object-with-or-without)

There is such code:

```
class MojaKlasa{
public:
  MojaKlasa(){}
  MojaKlasa(int i){}
  void fun(){}
};

int main()
{
  MojaKlasa a;
  a.fun();

  MojaKlasa b(1);
  b.fun();

  MojaKlasa c(); //  initialize with default constructor
  //c.fun(); error: request for member ‘fun’ in ‘c’, which is of non-class type ‘MojaKlasa()’

  return 0;
}
```

- Why is there error for object c?
- What is the way to make it work?
- What does really mean MojaKlasa c() - is it function declaraton?

Comment: Lookup **Most Vexing parse** in C++.

Comment: It's not the most vexing parse, the most vexing parse is when you try to use a value initialized temporary as initializer in a direct-initialized declaration.

Answer (score 4):

```
MojaKlasa c();
```

This declares a function called `c` returning `MojaKlasa`, it's not an object declaration. If you want to declare a local object you need to omit the parentheses. It's just a language rule that the compiler has to interpret this form as a function declaration.

```
MojaKlasa c;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MojaKlasa c();
```

defines a function returning a MojaKlasa object.

```
MojaKlasa c;
```

defines an object c of type MojaKlasa.