# C++ Request for member, which is of non-class type (when using class template, can't define in the main)

Tags: c++

**On my main i can't add a note on my new Object of the Class Trabalho

```
ass.add_nota(num);
**
```

There is a error on my compilation.

My "Trabalho.h" code:

```html
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
//#include "Enunciado.h"
//#include "Pessoa.h"

using namespace std;

class Estudante;
class Enunciado;

template <class T>
class Trabalho{
  static int id_auxiliar;
  string texto;
  int ano;
  int id;
  vector<float> calif;
  T* Enun;
  vector<Estudante*> estudantes;
  vector<Enunciado*> enunciados;

public:
  Trabalho();
  Trabalho(string texto, vector<Estudante*> est, T* en, int ano);
  ~Trabalho();
  void set_texto(string texto);
  string get_texto();
  void add_nota(float nota);
  void add_enun(Enunciado* en){Enun = en;};
  int get_id(){return id;};
  int get_ano() {return ano;};
  void reutilizar(int id_enun);
  vector<float> get_calif() {return calif;};
  vector<Estudante*> get_estudantes() {return estudantes;};
  Enunciado* get_enunciado() {return Enun;};



};

#endif
```

And my main code:

```html
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
 int n;
 int m;

 Pesquisa ah();

 float num = 1.1;

 Trabalho<Pesquisa> ass();
 Trabalho<Pesquisa>* tass = new Trabalho<Pesquisa>();

 ass.add_nota(num);
 tass->add_nota(num);
```

```html
#ifndef ENUNCIADO_H_
#define ENUNCIADO_H_
#include "trabalho.h"
#include "Pessoa.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Enunciado
{
 static unsigned int id_auxiliar;
 const unsigned int id;
 string titulo;
 string descricao;
 vector<int> anos_utilizados;
 static unsigned int max_util;
public:
 Enunciado(string titulo, string descricao);
 virtual ~Enunciado();
 int get_id(){return id;};
 void set_titulo(string titulo);
 string get_titulo();
 void set_descricao(string descricao);
 string get_descricao();
 vector<int> get_anos_utilizados();
 void mod_max_util(int a);
};



class Pesquisa: public Enunciado{

 vector<string> ref;
public:
 Pesquisa(string tit, string des, vector<string> refe);

};

class Analise: public Enunciado{
  vector<string> repositorios;
public:
  Analise(string tit, string des, vector<string> repos);
};

class Desenvolvimento: public Enunciado{

public:
 Desenvolvimento(string tit, string des);

};


#endif
```

Both ways when i create a new Trabalho when i define my type (pesquisa is a class type on #include "Enunciado.h".

This is the two erros that appears:

> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   request for member 'add_nota' in 'ass', which is of non-class type 'Trabalho()'   Test.cpp    /Trabalho1/src  line 42 C/C++ Problem
>   "

And:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Method 'add_nota' could not be resolved Test.cpp    /Trabalho1/src  line 42 Semantic Error

Can anyone help?

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post a MCVE example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your Trabalho.h is not correct (has a #endif with no corresponding #if).

Comment: Where are your implementations? How do you compile that?

Comment: I didn't post all the code, because has too many lines

Comment: Read the help center article for a [mcve], and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 4):

Your error is in trying to call the default constructor as

```
Pesquisa ah();
```

or

```
Trabalho<Pesquisa> ass();
```

Unfortunately, C++ is very misleading in this and it would declare your variable `ass` of type `Trabalho<Pesquisa>()`, which means "a function of zero arguments returning `Trabalho<Pesquisa>`" and that's exactly that the compiler error says: a function type is not a class type and as such does not have the member `add_nota`. Indeed, it does look *exactly* like a function declaration, if you look at it that way:

```
int main();
 ^    ^  ^
type    arguments
    name
```

It's a very common mistake, especially for those coming from a Java background. But it can easily catch a C++ programmer off guard as well. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116541/difference-between-creating-object-with-or-without) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318650/is-no-parentheses-on-a-constructor-with-no-arguments-a-language-standard), you can see that the same error message has perplexed a good many people.

If you have a compiler conforming to the C++11 language revision, try replacing all those occurrences by

```
Trabalho<Pesquisa> ass{};
```

If not, just leave

```
Trabalho<Pesquisa> ass;
```

Unlike in Java, this does not mean that the variable will stay uninitialized. It's the C++ way to call a default (zero-argument) constructor.

Comment: @Azevinho Welcome to SO. Seeing your code you will probably know most of the information in this answer but in the spirit of the site I wrote it to be helpful to those who came here in the future as well – perhaps by searching for the exact error message you got!

Comment: At this moment, i moved everything from the file.cpp to the file.h and remove the "()" bracket and it's running everything smoothly atm.
EDIT: Very thanks mate !

Comment: @Azevinho No problem :-) If the answer helped please consider giving it the tick mark ;-)

Comment: I still cant do it xD no more then 15 marks, some protective stuff from the SO