# Most vexing parse

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I got the code from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
class Timer {
 public:
  Timer();
};

class TimeKeeper {
 public:
  TimeKeeper(const Timer& t);

  int get_time()
  {
      return 1;
  }
};

int main() {
  TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());
  return time_keeper.get_time();
}
```

From the looks of it, it should get compile error due to the line:

```
TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());
```

But it only happens if  `return time_keeper.get_time();` is present.

Why would this line even matter, the compiler would spot ambiguity on `time_keeper(Timer() )` construction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is there no call to the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());` is interpreted as a function declaration and not as a variable definition. This, by itself, is not an error, but when you try to access the `get_time()` member of time_keeper (which is a function, not a TimeKeeper instance), your compiler fails.

This is how your compiler view the code:

```
int main() {
  // time_keeper gets interpreted as a function declaration with a function argument.
  // This is definitely *not* what we expect, but from the compiler POV it's okay.
  TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer (*unnamed_fn_arg)());

  // Compiler complains: time_keeper is function, how on earth do you expect me to call
  // one of its members? It doesn't have member functions!
  return time_keeper.get_time();
}
```

Comment: While I know the standard says in §13.1/3 that the Timer function type is adjusted to become a pointer to function type in this situation, but why would anyone want it to be adjusted to begin with? It seemed to me that §13.1/3 created the whole 'Most vexing parse' problem?