# C++ skipping line of code?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, skip

#### Background

I am writing a multi-threaded, websocket server in C++.

#### Problem

When I try to integrate my HTTP parser, `MKFAHTTPRequest Request( std::string( Buffer ) );` gets completely skipped during execution.

I've cleaned the project and added -Wall and -Werror (which should tell me that `Request` is an unused variable, but it doesn't).

```
void operator()(){
    while( true ){
        if( m_Socket->is_open() ){
            char Buffer[1024]; 

            boost::system::error_code Error; 

            std::cout << "MKFAConnection::operator()() - Reading..." << std::endl;
            m_Socket->read_some( boost::asio::buffer( Buffer, sizeof( Buffer ) ), Error ); 

            if( !Error ){
                // This line is getting skipped!?!?!?
                MKFAHttpRequest Request( std::string( Buffer ) );

                m_Socket->write_some( boost::asio::buffer( std::string( "Hello World" ) ) ); 

            } else break; 

        } else break; 

    }

}
```

Comment: What logging have you done to see if it really is skipped, or for example, just gives an error?

Comment: How do you know it is skipped?

Comment: Yes, I can do a `cout` before and after that line. If I step through this function in the debugger, it stops on every line except that one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse(C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> MKFAHttpRequest Request( std::string( Buffer ) );
> ```

This line doesn't do what you think it does. You think it defines an object named `Request` of type `MKFAHttpRequest` and initializes the object with a temporary object of type `std::string`.

In fact, it declares a function named `Request` which accepts a single parameter of type `std::string` and returns an object of type `MKFAHttpRequest`.

This is related to (or perhaps an example of) the most vexing parse.

Perhaps one of these will make it better:

```
MKFAHttpRequest Request( (std::string( Buffer )) );
MKFAHttpRequest Request{ std::string( Buffer ) };
MKFAHttpRequest Request = std::string( Buffer );
MKFAHttpRequest Request = MKFAHttpRequest(std::string( Buffer ));
```

Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MKFAHttpRequest Request( std::string( Buffer ) );
```

is as a function declaration in C++. 
Try this

```
std::string s( Buffer );
MKFAHttpRequest Request( s );
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think the best solution is C++11's uniform initializer syntax:

```
MKFAHttpRequest Request{ std::string( Buffer ) };
```

However, an alternative would be simply using static_cast:

```
MKFAHttpRequest Request( static_cast<std::string>( Buffer ) };
```

static_cast will find a matching constructor call for std::string, taking char*. It also makes it clear that you are, in effect, "casting" from char* to std::string in order to call the MKFAHttpRequest constructor.