# Object creation Anomaly

Tags: c++

I am using `Code::Blocks 10.05` with `GCC` on `Windows 7`. I was experimenting with `C++ constructors` and I compiled and executed the following program.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
    public:
    base() {
        cout<<"\n Constructor Invoked\n";
    }
};

int main() {
  base ob;
  return 0;
}
```

The output was as expected and shown below.

```
Constructor Invoked
```

But while typing the program I accidentally compiled the following program. To my surprise it compiled without any error or warning.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class base {
    public:
    base() {
        cout<<"\n Constructor Invoked\n";
    }
};

int main() {
  base ob();
  return 0;
}
```

But the program didn't give any output, just a blank screen. But no error or warning. Since it hasn't called the constructor I assume no object was created. But why no error or warning? Am I missing something very obvious?

When I added the line `cout<<sizeof(ob);` I got the following error message.

```
error: ISO C++ forbids applying 'sizeof' to an expression of function type
```

So what is `ob`? Is it considered as a function or an object?

Please somebody explain the line of code `base ob();` and what actually happens in the memory when that line of code is executed?

Thank you.

Comment: It is a function declaration. There are many duplicates, although they might be hard to find.

Comment: Read about [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). It's one of the reasons that [uniform initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) was put in the C++11 standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared a function with

```
base ob();
```

It will do nothing. 
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)