# Why this statement does not call the constructors - C++

Tags: c++, templates, most-vexing-parse

A template class and a normal class:

```
template <typename Type>
class Holder
{
public:
    Holder(const Type& value) : held_(value)
    {
        cout << "Holder(const Type& value)" << endl;
    }
    Type& Ref() { return held_; }
private:
    Type held_;
};

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const Animal& rhs) { cout << "Animal(const Animal& rhs)" << endl; }
    Animal() { cout << "Animal()" << endl; }
    ~Animal() { cout << "~Animal" << endl; }
    void Print() const { cout << "Animal::Print()" << endl; }
};
```

Then I want to instantiate a `Holder<Animal>` with this statement `Holder<Animal> a(Animal());`, however, it fails. I mean `Animal()` is not treated as a temporary object. And this statement doesn't call `Holder`'s constructor.

If someone could explain? I'm not clear. I'm guessing `a` becomes a type here. Then, I use `Holder<Animal> a = Holder<Animal>(Animal());`, it works well. So, there are some cases here:

1. `Holder<Animal> a(Animal()); a.Ref().Print(); // error`
2. `Holder<Animal> a = Holder<Animal>(Animal()); a.Ref().Print(); // ok`
3. `Holder<int> b(4); b.Ref() = 10; cout << b.Ref() << endl; //ok`

Can explain? I'm just a little confused with the first statement. And the error information this statement causes:

`GCC4.7.2`: `error: request for member 'Ref' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'Holder<Animal>(Animal (*)())'`

`VS10`: `error C2228: left of '.Ref' must have class/struct/union`, `error C2228: left of '.Print' must have class/struct/union`

Comment: A good question... I don't really know the answer. But won't `Animal()` be treated as a temporary object? Doesn't it go out of scope imemdiately?

Comment: @Dariusz no it would last until the `;` is reached, i.e. until `a`'s constructor is completed.

Comment: @ArneMertz ok, by "immediately" i meant after that line's execution is finished, which means after the constructor. So since we take a reference to that object, the reference will become invalid? ... Ah, it won't, holder member `held_` is not a reference, never mind.

Comment: @Dariusz that's the C++03 way to do it - the temporary gets copied and the copy survives. In C++11, the constructor would take the parameter by value and move-construct the member variable from it. That way the temporary `Animal` would get moved twice and end up in the `held_` member variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse(C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement `Holder<Animal> a(Animal());` does not create a variable, but declares a function that returns a `Holder<Animal>` and that takes a function in parameter. It's usually called the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), because of this ambiguity (that one would expect a variable rather than a function declaration).

Herb Sutter explains the different possible syntaxes [here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/). In C++11, a possible solution is:

```
auto a = Holder<Animal> {};
```

Comment: And the solution is `Holder<Animal> a{Animal()};`

Comment: @BenVoigt why don't you use uniform initialization in both cases? ;)

Comment: Or use surrounding parens if your C++ compiler isn't from this decade: `Holder<Animal> a((Animal()));` *yuck*.

Answer (score 3):

You are victim to the "most vexing parse":

`Holder<Animal> a(Animal());` is parsed as a function with name `a`, that returns a `Holder<Animal>` and takes as parameter another function, which has no parameters and returns an `Animal`.

In C++11 you can solve that problem by using uniform initialization:

`Holder<Animal> a{Animal{}};`

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I'll update my post to make it clear.

Comment: It wasn't about the English - only about the missing error messages ;-) I would never judge anyone's English, since I am not a native speaker myself :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be careful next time :)