# invalid initialization when using references with polymorphism

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, g++, polymorphism

I stumbled on a weird compiler error when working on one of my projects. I manage to reproduce the error with this small code

```
#include <iostream>

class base
{
private:
    char f;
public:
    char get_char()
    {
    return f;
    }
    base(char f)
    {
    this->f = f;
    }
};


class derived : public base
{
private:
    std::string msg;
public:
    const std::string &get_message() const
    {
    return msg;
    }
    derived(const std::string& msg) : base(msg.c_str()[0])
    {
    this->msg = msg;
    }
};

void print_base(base &base_obj)
{
    std::cout << base_obj.get_char() << std::endl;
}


const char *input = "Hello World!";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // This line compiles
    //derived d = derived(std::string(argv[0]));

    // This also works
    //derived d(argv[0]);

    // This line gives compiler error (see below)
    derived d(std::string(argv[0]));

    print_base(d);

    return 0;
}
```

The line that does not work gives me compiler error:

```
ain.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:50:17: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘base&’ from an rvalue of type ‘derived (*)(std::string*) {aka derived (*)(std::basic_string<char>*)}’
     print_base(d);
             ^
main.cpp:34:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void print_base(base&)’
 void print_base(base &base_obj)
```

Why doesn't the second way of initializing compile?

ADDITIONAL INFO:

Compiler: g++

Comment: [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
derived d(std::string(argv[0]));
```

Declares a function named `d` that takes a pointer to `std::string` as an argument. This is one of the most vexing parses, since it does something it may not look like it should do. It is the same as

```
derived d(std::string* argv);
```

To fix this, leave out the explicit string construction, or use braces or double parentheses.

```
derived d(argv[0]);
```

or

```
derived d{std::string(argv[0])}; // C++11
```

or

```
derived d((std::string(argv[0])));
```

Answer (score 3):

The clue in the error message is:

```
from an rvalue of type ‘derived (*)(std::string*)
```

and indicates you're suffering from the C++ [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Answer (score 2):

```
derived d(std::string(argv[0])); //function declaration (your code!)
```

is equivalent to this:

```
derived d(std::string argv[0]);
```

which is a function declaration (not object declaration).

Use uniform-initialization-syntax to avoid such problem:

```
derived d { std::string(argv[0]) }; //object declaration
```

Hope that helps.