# Can't get composition right

Tags: c++, object-composition

I'm honestly embarassed I have to ask but I'm stuck on that.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Obj
{
};


class Test
{
private:
  Obj a;

public:
  Test(Obj _a)
    : a(_a) 
  {}
};


int main() {

  Obj ob();
  Test t(ob);

  return 0;
```

}

I get this error:

```
t.cpp:24: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test::Test(Obj (&)())’
t.cpp:15: note: candidates are: Test::Test(Obj)
t.cpp:10: note:                 Test::Test(const Test&)
```

I don't get it. The same snippet works just fine with built in types (integers and stuff).

Comment: This is "the most vexing parse".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse(C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Comment: No need to be embarrassed, they call it "vexing" for a reason.

Comment: Oh gosh. This is where sleep deprivation can lead us. Thank you guys though ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Obj ob();` declares a `ob` to be a function taking no parameters and returning `Obj`.

If you want to default construct an `Obj`, use `Obj ob;` or `Obj ob{};`.

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
Obj ob();
```

does not create an object `ob`. It declares a function that takes nothing as input and returns a `Obj`.

Change it to:

```
Obj ob;
```