# slot error using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I am trying to implement a basic http connection http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt into Qt but I have difficultly implementing the slot. I am a Qt novice.

C:\Qt5\Tools\QtCreator\bin\miniHTTP\main.cpp:10: error: request for member 'Test' in 'mTest', which is of non-class type 'coreEng()'
     mTest.Test();

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <coreeng.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    coreEng mTest;
    mTest.Test();
    return a.exec();
}
```

//coreeng.h

```
#ifndef COREENG_H
#define COREENG_H
#include <QDebug>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class coreEng : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit coreEng(QObject *parent = 0);
    void Test();
private slots:

public slots:
    void connect();
    void url();
    void finishedSlot();


private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* nam;

};

#endif // COREENG_H
```

//coreeng.cpp

```
#include "coreeng.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>

coreEng::coreEng(QNetworkReply* parent) :
    QObject(parent)

{
}

void coreEng::Test();

void coreEng::connect(){
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void coreEng::url(){
    QUrl url("http://www.forum.nokia.wiki");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}


void coreEng::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){

    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {

        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
        QImage pic = imageReader.read();

        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
        QString string(bytes); // string
    }

    else
    {

    }

    delete reply;

}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse change  `coreEng mTest();` to  `coreEng mTest;`

Comment: @drescherjm  Thank you. That appears to of got me a little farther, but I am still having issues initializing the object ->  coreeng.cpp:8: error: prototype for 'coreEng::coreEng(QNetworkReply*)' does not match any in class 'coreEng'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is you are running into the most vexing parse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

[Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Change

```
coreEng mTest();
```

to

```
coreEng mTest;
```

A second problem is your constructor in coreeng.cpp has the wrong signature

Change:

```
coreEng::coreEng(QNetworkReply*) :
    QObject(parent)
```

to

```
   coreEng::coreEng(QObject* parent) :
        QObject(parent)
```

Comment: Also I recommend not changing the original question code while we help fix the problems because the first part of my answer no longer makes sense.

Comment: I apologies, I actually thought it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `void Test();` as a member function in the header file and have not implemented it in the cpp file. You should implement it :

```
void coreEng::Test()
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried that before, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other problems already described, your implementation of finished slot doesn't have the same signature of as the function definition.  In your .h file you have:

```
void finishedSlot();
```

Whereas your .cpp has:

```
void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    /*code here*/
}
```

So to summarise:

1. Add an implementation of your test function:

   void coreEng::Test() { /*code here*/ }
2. Fix the signature of your constructor so that .cpp and .h files agree:

   coreEng::coreEng(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) { /*code here*/ }
3. Fix the signature of your finishedSlot so that .cpp and .h files agree:

   void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply);

These changes will at least get you to the stage that you're compiling successfully.