# Create std::string from std::istreambuf_iterator, strange syntax quirk

Tags: c++, stl

I found somewhere the following idiom for reading a file into a string:

```
std::ifstream file("path/to/some/file.ext");
std::string contents(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>())
);
```

Which works just fine as it is. However, if I remove the parentheses around the second iterator argument, that is:

```
std::string contents(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

As soon as I try to call any method on the string object, for example:

```
const char *buffer = contents.c_str();
```

I get a compile error of the form:

`error: request for member 'c_str' in 'contents', which is of non-class type 'std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)()) {aka std::basic_string<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())}'`

Also if I try to assign that string to another:

```
std::string contents2 = contents;
```

I get an error of the form:

`error: conversion from 'std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)()) {aka std::basic_string<char>(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char> > (*)())}' to non-scalar type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' requested`

Why is this? I can see no reason for those parentheses being needed, much less affect the type definition of the `contents` variable. I am using g++ 4.8.2.

Comment: So many Most Vexing Parse questions here, but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec?rq=1) is pretty similar.

Comment: That's great as long as you know what Most Vexing Parse is. If you don't (like I didn't), it's difficult to even know what to look for. Which is why I decided to ask this question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is an example of [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse):

```
std::string contents(
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
);
```

The statement is parsed as the declaration of a function named `contents` that takes two parameters. One parameter that is a variable named `file` of type `std::istreambuf_iterator`, and a second one that is a function that takes no arguments and returns an `std::istreambuf_iterator`. Specification of function parameter names are optional.

Wrapping at least one of the expressions in parenthesis causes it to be parsed as a variable definition.

C++11 solves this problem with its provision of *uniform-initialization*:

```
std::string contents{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, {}};
```

Comment: What's `{}` in `std::string contents{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, {}};`? Could you please explain that in more detail for me?

Comment: @John It's a quick way of initializing a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` with the default-constructor without having to write out the whole thing. It's called list-initialization. If you had a function `void foo(int x);` you can call it like `foo({});` and it'll just make a `int` with the value `0`. So it does the same as the first code sample.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The list-initialization could deduce the suitable type?

Comment: @John It doesn't deduce anything. The complier sees the type you're trying to initialize and uses the list-initializer to construct the object and call the appropriate constructor.