# Function definition or variable definition?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, most-vexing-parse

Why does the compiler interpret this line as a function definition and not as a variable definition:

```
Y y(X());
```

in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct X {
  X() { std::cout << "X"; }
};

struct Y {
  Y(const X &x) { std::cout << "Y"; }
  void f() { std::cout << "f"; }
};

int main() {
  Y y(X());
  y.f();
}
```

VS2010 gives the following error on line "y.f();"

```
left of '.f' must have class/struct/union
```

Which part of the standard describes this behavior?
The answer to the following question doesn't give details about it:
[Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parsec)

Comment: This is not a compiler bug by the way. It's the most vexing parse problem, cunningly disguised.

Comment: Voted to reopen based on the edit - a quote from the standard would actually be useful. 6.8 talks about disamiguating expression statements vs. declarations, but the most vexing parse is actually an ambiguity between two declarations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this :

[*`float foo( int () )`*](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=float+foo%28+int+%28%29+%29)

This declares a function `foo` ( accepting a function returning `int` ) returning `float`.

Now read

```
Y y(X());
```

as `y` as function (accepting a function returning `X`) returning `Y`

The problem arises due to [C++ most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Can be solved with :

```
 Y y{ X() }; // requires C++11
```

or

```
Y y( ( X() ) );
  // ^     ^ notice parenthesis
```

---

**Update** based on edit:

A *quote from the standard* :

> **[§ 8.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf#section.8.2) Ambiguity resolution [dcl.ambig.res]**
>
> 1 - The ambiguity arising from the similarity between a function-style cast and a declaration mentioned in 6.8 can also occur in the context of a declaration. **In that context, the choice is between a function declaration with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter name and an object declaration with a function-style cast as the initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in [6.8](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf#section.6.8), the resolution is to consider any construct that could possibly be a declaration a declaration.** [Note: a declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by a nonfunction-style cast, by a = to indicate initialization or by removing the redundant parentheses around the parameter name. ]

```
[Example:

struct S {
    S(int);
};

void foo(double a)
{
   S w(int(a));  // function declaration
   S x(int());   // function declaration
   S y((int)a);  // object declaration
   S z = int(a); // object declaration
}
—end example]
```

Similarly other examples following this.

Comment: `Y y = X();` isn't equivalent to `Y y{ X() };`. Right solution in C++03 is `Y y( (X()) );`

Comment: However in some cases `Y y = X();` will work as intended and is more readable.

Answer (score 5):

[Most vexing parse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). `Y y(X())` is actually function declaration with name `y`, that returns `Y` and receives argument of type function, that returns `X` and receives nothing.

It's solved in C++11 with usage of `{}` for construct object.