# Constructing priority_queue instance with Compare instance of different type

Tags: c++, gcc, constructor, containers

Could anybody please explain why my compiler (GCC) accepts the code below as valid?

```
priority_queue<int, deque<int>, less<int>> pq(greater<int>());
```

I expect this constructor (for an instance of type having `less<int>` as `Comparator`, as specified for  `priority_queue` instance `pq`) to be incompatible with an instance of `greater<int>` (passed as constructor parameter), which is a different type from `less<int>`. But GCC accepts this for some reason...

Comment: most-vexing parse strikes back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below statement:

```
priority_queue<int, deque<int>, less<int>> pq(greater<int>());
```

is actually parsed by the compiler as a **declaration** of `pq` function that returns an instance of `priority_queue`, and which takes a single parameter, being a pointer to a function that takes no arguments, and returns an instance of `greater<int>` type. This is known as [*Most-vexing parse*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5926103/3953764).

You will see an error if you write:

```
priority_queue<int, deque<int>, less<int> > pq((greater<int>()));
//                                             ^              ^
```

or (in C++11):

```
priority_queue<int, deque<int>, less<int>> pq(greater<int>{});
//                                                        ^^
```

Comment: Exactly. My blunder. :) Sure, what can be parsed as a function declaration will be.