# Unexpected compiler behaviour with empty std::vector in constructor

Tags: c++, g++

I have a question about a compiler/language behaviour that I expected to behave differently.
Why does the following code compile?

```
#include <vector>
class A { }; 
int main() {
    A a(std::vector<int>()); 
}
```

It does not compile with `std::vector<int>(0)` or other values. It does however compile if you give `std::vector<int>(*)` a pointer. It also works with other types than "`int`". I expected the code to not work at all. Can someone explain to me what's happening?

Here is a code snipped on cpp.sh for reference: http://cpp.sh/4l3a

I use gcc version 4.8.4.

Comment: Since it _does_ compile, you should assume that it's supposed to, and that we can't guess why you think it shouldn't. _What was your expectation?_

Comment: sorry for the duplicate answer.  @LightnessRacesinOrbit correctly assumed my expectation in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you expected it to fail compilation because `A` has no constructor taking a vector.

```
A a(std::vector<int>());
```

This is not a declaration of an `A`, though. It's a declaration of a function called `a`, taking a pointer (with no name) to a function returning `std::vector<int>`, and returning `A`.

When you changed it to this:

```
A a(std::vector<int>(0));
```

the use of an integer literal forces the parser to recognise this as an object instantiation instead, which of course fails because `A` has no constructor taking a vector.

You can force the parser's recognition in your first case, too, using an extra set of parentheses:

```
A a((std::vector<int>()));
```

This is an instance of the [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5926103/560648).

Comment: You are right. I supposed it shouldn't work because there is no constructor defined in A for std::vector. Thank you very much for your answer. It helped me a lot! And I learned something new about the language. Couldn't find anything by searching a I didn't know what to search for.

Comment: @Angew: thanks for clarifying this