# Object not created even if default constructor is present?

Tags: c++

In the below two codes why the first code's object of class student "s2" is not created whereas object "s2" of code 2 is created. Why are just the "()" creating such difference?

```
    ///////////////CODE 1/////////////////
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Student
    {
        int marks;
    public:
        Student()
        {
            cout << "In" << endl;;
        }
        Student(int x)
        {
            cout << "Out" << endl;
            marks = x;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Student s1(100);
        Student s2();
        Student s3 = 100;
        return 0;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
```

This is another code in which the "()" are absent i

```
///////////////CODE 2/////////////////
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Student
    {
        int marks;
    public:
        Student()
        {
            cout << "In" << endl;;
        }
        Student(int x)
        {
            cout << "Out" << endl;
            marks = x;
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Student s1(100);
        Student s2;
        Student s3 = 100;
        return 0;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Please use only the correct tag.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parse)

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the issue of the [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parse). In essence, the line `Student s2();` is not a variable declaration: you're declaring a function named `s2` that takes no arguments.

Either use `Student s2;` or `Student s2{};`.

Comment: I think "most vexing parse" refers to specifically when there is an argument that looks like `Student s2(T())`.

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, you're right. I'll modify my answer to make that clearer. I don't know of any other searchable name for this issue, though.

Comment: afaik `Student s2()`  is a classical example of mvp

Comment: @bolov looking around suggests that `Student s2();` is a vexing parse, but not the "most vexing parse" as defined by Meyers. I don't think it really makes a difference, though...