# C++ Constructor not been called

Tags: c++, constructor

I was pretty sure the calling of B(A()) will call the defined constructor of B in my code.
But I was surprised to find out that it didn't call to my constructor B and of course didn't print "Constructor B".

So, to which constructor this code is calling (what is the signature of this constructor that it's calling to)?

```
struct A
{
    
};

struct B
{
    B(const A a) { std::cout << "Constructor B" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    B(A());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most vexing parse

Comment: Try to compile it with gcc!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926103/most-vexing-parse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't construct an object with type `B` as you expected, then no constructor is called.

When declaring variables we can add (unnecessary) parentheses around the variable name, i.e. `int (a);` has the same effect as `int a;`. Similarly, `B(A());` is same as `B A();`, which declares a function named `A`, which takes no parameters and returns `B`.

As the workaround you can change `()` to `{}`, e.g.

```
B(A{});
B{A()};
B{A{}};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sS8W9BqbPc7U0UGc)