# What's the differences between Test t; and Test t();? if Test is a class

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no call to the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor)

I am using Visual studio 2012, Suppose Test is a class

```
class Test
{
};
```

When I create a new instance of Test, what's the difference of the following two ways?

way 1

```
Test t;
```

way 2

```
Test t();
```

I got this question in the code below, originally, I defined an instance of A in way 2, I got only one error because B does not provide an default constructor, but when I define it in way 1, I got an extra error.

```
class B
{
    B(int i){}
};

class A
{
    A(){}
    B b;
};

int main(void) 
{ 
    A a(); // define object a in way 2

    getchar() ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

if I define a in way 1

```
A a;
```

I will got another error said

> error C2248: 'A::A' : cannot access private member declared in class
>   'A'

So I guess there must be some differences between the two ways.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[image]

`Test t;` defines a variable called `t` of type `Test`.

`Test t();` declares a function called `t` that takes no parameters and returns a `Test`.

Comment: +1 for the picture :-)

Comment: well, what a stupid question, I am sure I know that before, but... it's not my day today, :(

Comment: Am I the only one that just saved that pic to desktop ?

Comment: And the memes invade StackOverflow...

Answer (score 17):

> **What is the Difference between two declarations?**

```
A a();
```

Declares a function and not an object. It is one of the **[Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)** in C++.
It declares a function by the name `a` which takes no parameters and returns a type `A`.

```
A a;
```

Creates a object named `a` of the type `A` by calling its default constructor.

> **Why do you get the compilation error?**

For a class default access specifier is `private` so You get the error because your class constructor is `private` and it cannot be called while creating the object with above syntax.