# list<string> test() and list<string> test difference?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error on calling default constructor with empty set of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/error-on-calling-default-constructor-with-empty-set-of-brackets)
>   [What's the differences between Test t; and Test t();? if Test is a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686298/whats-the-differences-between-test-t-and-test-t-if-test-is-a-class)

What is the difference between this code the first compiles the second doesn't. I am pretty new to C++.

**FIRST SAMPLE**

```
list<string> str;
list<string>::iterator it;

it = str.begin();
```

**SECOND SAMPLE**

```
list<string> str();
list<string>::iterator it;

it = str.begin();
```

I thought that calling without the parantethiss calls the default constructor witch is the same to () variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list<string> str;
```

declares a variable.

```
list<string> str();
```

declares a function that takes no parameters and returns a `list<string>`.

This is commonly known as a vexing parse.

Comment: Didn't knew that C++ syntax can often be confusing.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`list<string> str();` is treated as a function prototype declaration. See ["Most Vexing Parse"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).