# Error in executing the constructor of another class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no call to the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor)

Please have a look at the following code

**UIHandler.h**

```
#pragma once
class UIHandler
{
public:
    UIHandler();
    ~UIHandler(void);

private:
    //Book *books;
};
```

**UIHandler.cpp**

```
    #include "UIHandler.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    UIHandler::UIHandler()
    {        
       {
       //action once code goes here
       }        
        int selection;

        cout << "..............Welcome to DigitalLab Library..........." << endl << endl;;
        cout << "Kindly press, " << endl;
        cout << "1. Enter Books" << endl;
        cout << "2. Display Books"<< endl;
        cout << "3. Member Area" << endl;

        cout << "Your Selection: ";
        cin >> selection;
    }        

    UIHandler::~UIHandler(void)
    {
    }
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "UIHandler.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    UIHandler a();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I am unable to execute the constructor in UIHandler, because the code runs but nothing happens. If I pass a parameter to the UIHandler constructor, it works as it should be, even I take no use of the constructor. Why is that? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a function `a` which returns `UIHandler` type, see [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

update

```
UIHandler a();
```

to

```
UIHandler a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but Duplicate? Where did I open another question like this? Normally when an duplicate, the duplicated thread is produced. Where is it?

Comment: a dup means this question is asked my other person already. :) you can find the answer from previous question

Comment: ohhh!! OK..Luckily I have the answer now anyway, without looking at those ;)

Comment: no problem, welcome to SO

Answer (score 1):

`UIHandler a();` is a function declaration, that will return `UIHandler` object. Remove `()` after `a`

**Upd:** changed definition to declaration. Thanks to @JesseGood

Comment: `declaration` not `definition`.

Comment: @JesseGood thank you. I'll fix. As if english is not my language, I always mix up terms (but not meaning, of course)