# What is the difference between MyRectangle mr = MyRectangle(); and MyRectangle mr2 ();

Tags: c++

I notice the former enters the constructor I made even if the constructor has no arguments while the latter only enters the constructor I made only if it requires arguments.

**WIN**

```
// ConsoleApplication11.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;


class myRectangle {
    int width;
    public:
        int getWith();
        void setWidth(int newWidth) {width = newWidth;};
        myRectangle (int);
        ~myRectangle ();
};
myRectangle::myRectangle (int w) {
    width = w;
    cout << "myRectangel Constructor\n";
}

myRectangle::~myRectangle() {
    cout << "destructor\n";
}

void runObject();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    runObject();
    int exit; cout << "\n\n"; 
    cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}

void runObject() 
{
    myRectangle mr (5);
}
```

**FAIL**
    // ConsoleApplication11.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;


class myRectangle {
    int width;
    public:
        int getWith();
        void setWidth(int newWidth) {width = newWidth;};
        myRectangle ();
        ~myRectangle ();
};
myRectangle::myRectangle () {
    cout << "myRectangel Constructor\n";
}

myRectangle::~myRectangle() {
    cout << "destructor\n";
}

void runObject();

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    runObject();
    int exit; cout << "\n\n"; 
    cin >> exit;
    return 0;
}

void runObject() 
{
    myRectangle mr ();
}
```

Comment: You may want to sit down. `MyRectangle mr2();` is a [function declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor).

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myRectangle mr(5);
```

Here, `mr` is a `myRectangle` instance, constructed using the `myRectangle` constructor that takes a single int parameter.

```
myRectangle mr ();
```

Here, `mr` is a function with no parameters and returning a `myRectangle`. It is a confusing parse that can be avoided in C++11 by using brace initialization. It can also be avoided by omitting the brackets:

```
myRectangle mr; //  C++03 and C++11
myRectangle{};  //  C++11
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside:

```
 void runObject() 
 {
     myRectangle mr ();
 }
```

`myRectangle mr();` is not creating an object of `myRectangle`, but rather, declares a function with name `mr` that takes no parameter and return type is `myRectangle`.

Comment: For you, maybe, but not for the compiler. To instantiate an object without using constructor parameters, omit the parenthesis: `myRectangle me;`

Answer (score 1):

`myRectangle mr = myRectangle();` instantiates and constructs an instance of the class `myRectangle`. In contrast, `myRectangle mr ();` declares `mr` as a function returning `myRectangle` and taking no arguments.

Comment: You might note the existence of copy elision for `Foo f = Foo();`