# Creating C++ class instances globally within my main file

Tags: c++, class

I have a program with some classes for OpenGL stuff e.g. Window, Program etc.

I want the instances of the Window and Program classes which I use in my main file to be global for the main file, I'd been doing this for a while with Window like this

```
//Outside main()
Window window
(
    "test",    //title
    1366,      //width
    768,       //height
);
```

Then I can use this instance in the rest of the main file e.g.

```
//Within main()

window.create();

window.refresh();
```

etc.

Now when I try to make a global instance of Program I do it like this:

```
//Just below Window, still outside main()
Program program();    //No arguments for the constructor for Program
```

Then when I try to use it in my main function like this:

```
program.addShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "vertex_shader_source.glsl");
```

I get the error:

```
request for member 'addShader' in 'program', which is of non-class type 'Program()'
```

Having looked into this it looks like the compiler thinks that my initialisation of the instance before main() is a function instead so it thinks I'm trying to call methods on a function which obviously doesn't work.

I just can't work out how to make this work in the way that it does for Window, the key differences that I can tell which might mean Window works and Program doesn't are:

- The constructor for Window has arguments and Program doesn't.
- I have other instances of the Program class in main() other than this global one, of course they have different name but still it might cause some problem?

Comment: `Program program();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Duplicates: [why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810570/why-is-there-no-call-to-the-constructor)

Comment: Related: [Default constructor with empty brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/180172/873025)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Program program;
```

instead of

```
Program program();
```

You do not need to use parens for constructor without parameters. Actually the second construct is interpreted as function declaration (function without parameters returning `Program`).

Comment: The compiler would interpret it as a function declaration (just a precision as this is the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

You've discovered what's called the [**most vexing parse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Indeed, when you do that:

```
Program program();
```

it is ambiguous, as you could be doing two things:

- Creating a variable `program` which ctor takes no argument
- Declaring a function called `program` which returns a `Program` and takes no argument

And the C++ standard imposes that a compiler choose the second possibility when it encounters this code.

To avoid this problem, just remove the parens

```
//Declares and defines a new program variable by invoking the default ctor
Program program;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't write it like this:

```
Program program();
```

because the parser thinks you just declared a function called "program" with no arguments, which return Program instance.

This is the correct way to define an object using its default constructor:

```
Program program;
```