# QT - pointer to QColor works direct access don't

Tags: c++, qt

I got following issue:
That's work:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QColor>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QColor *c = new QColor();
    c->setRgb(12,123,13);
    return a.exec();
}
```

but this don't:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QColor>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QColor c();
    c.setRgb(123,213,2);
    return a.exec();
}
```

Qtcreator get me:

> request for member 'setRgb' in 'c'
>   which is of non-class type 'Qcolor()'

What is going on?

**EDIT**
OK solution was use Qcolor c without '()', but what if it is member of class? Then direct access still doesn't work... ie:

```
class X{

QColor c;

  void func(){
     c.setRgb(1,2,3);
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Comment: Now it's legal C++. Your tools may be bugged. What error do you get?

Comment: My app crashed... (it must be a reason because if i change on c->setRgb(1,2,3) and Qcolor *c; app works...

Comment: Fine, then it doesn't fall in the scope of this question anymore. It depends on how you use `c`, which you doesn't show in the last piece of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

```
QColor c();
```

is a function declaration. Change it to

```
QColor c;
```

That's a possible duplicate of hundreds of similar questions....

Comment: could you explain it a little more? Even Qtcreator tipping '()'

Comment: @John: I have no idea what's Qtcreator, neither I know Qt. Probably because your code completion utility expects you to type something between the parentheses or delete them otherwise. See the dupe I posted above.

Comment: Thx... last question: what is about if Qcolor is member of class? Then it doesn't work still

Comment: What exactly is your code? If you write `QColor c();` as a member of a class then it's still a function declaration, so it won't work. When you remove the `()` it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Declare like

QColor c;