# Is the constructor getting called here?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>

class _ctor
{
public:
_ctor() { std::cout<<"\nCtor";}
~_ctor(){ std::cout<<"\nDtor";}
};

_ctor A(); // --> Is the Constructor Really called? I do not see the Output printed
//_ctor A;

int main(){
return 0;
}
```

The Output of the above code is given in this [Link](http://www.ideone.com/Bqt9N)
I don't see the constructor getting called, what could be the problem?? If it is not supposed to be called then what does this mean `_ctor A();`?

Comment: FYI the name `_ctor` is reserved which makes your program ill-formed (this has nothing to do with the question which has already been answered). More details in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You declared a function called `A()` which returns a `_ctor`, and you never called that function.  You never even defined that function.

No, the constructor of _ctor is not being called.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no

Comment: interesting how this keeps cropping up here, when I first read of this I thought it a corner case.

Answer (score 5):

No, because you're actually declaring a function that takes no arguments and returns a `_ctor`. This is called ["the most vexing parse."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) You probably want this:

```
_ctor A;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a function named `A` that returns a ctor class object so no constructor is called.

If you want to create a global object of ctor class you can do:

```
_ctor A;
```

which calls the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For the constructor to be able to call, the program needs to instantiate class `_ctor`.

```
_ctor A();
```

The above statement is a prototype for function `A()` saying that it's return type is `_ctor`.