# Cast in constructors for c++ type

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
    {
        const std::string s1 = "ddd";
        std::string s2( std::string( s1 ) );
        std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
    }
```

The result is:
1
Why?
When I use -Wall flag, compiler write warning: the address of ‘std::string s2(std::string)’ will always evaluate as ‘true’

But this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    const std::string s1 = "ddd";
    std::string s2( ( std::string )( s1 ) );
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

The result:
ddd

It's normal result

Comment: Couldn't you just make the second line `std::string s2(s1);`  Why do you need to include the second `std::string`?

Comment: Why create an intermediate copy? Why not `std::string s2 = s1;`?

Comment: @Oscar: Your version creates an intermediate default initialized variable and then copies via the copy assignment operator. The correct version without anything intermediate is rho's.

Comment: @OscarKorz I read that, but it seems to me that the most vexing parse would only occur if you include the inner `std::string` as it then interprets `std::string` as a function (like @Xeo explains).  But I just tested it and it compiles fine without the inner `std::string`.  Seems to me if you leave out the inner type declaration you avoid the problem in the first place.  Perhaps I'm not understanding something, or I'm reading too heavily into the example.

Comment: @Xeo:  `std::string s2 = s1;` does not use an assignment operator, it uses the copy constructor.

Comment: @rhololkeolke I deleted my comment already because I was wrong. Your line doesn't trigger the most vexing parse. I was hoping I was quick enough that you wouldn't notice. :)

Comment: @James: My bad then, nvm me. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Most-vexing-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no/181463#181463).

```
std::string s2( std::string( s1 ) );
```

is parsed as the declaration of a "function taking a `std::string` parameter named `s1` and returning a `std::string`". You then try to print that function, which will first convert it to a function pointer (normal decay/conversion rule). Since the `operator<<` of `std::ostream` isn't overloaded for function pointers in general, it will try a conversion to bool, which succeeds, and since the function pointer is nonnull, it's converted to the boolean value `true`, which is printed as `1`.

Change it to

```
std::string s2( (std::string( s1 )) );
```

or even better, just

```
std::string s2( s1 );
```

Comment: @Oscar: Copy ctor > copy assignment operator. :)

Comment: `std::string s2 = s1;` calls the copy constructor because its a declaration.

Comment: @Oscar: Hm, my bad then. Nvm me. :)

Comment: @OscarKorz: Actually, that's a _[definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632)_.

Comment: @OscarKorz: Well, no problem then, just use one whenever you think the other should apply. `:)`