# (Simple Constructor Concept) Why doesn't Foo(); do anything?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, default-constructor

This is a simple C++ constructor concept I'm having trouble with.

Given this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo ()      {       cout << "Foo()"  << endl;     }
    ~Foo ()     {       cout << "~Foo()" << endl;     }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f1;
    Foo f2();
}
```

The output was:

```
Foo()
~Foo()
```

It seems like `Foo f2();` doesn't do anything. What *is* `Foo f2();` And *why* doesn't it do anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Comment: IMO this is not a dupe.  It's rather the question OP should have asked, but didn't know to.  See here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109993/guidelines-for-closing-questions-as-exact-duplicate

Comment: @Jason: I'd be cautious with using the term *concepts* in the context of C++ if not talking about [this kind of stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)). The title of your question is a bit confusing in that sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Foo f2();` declares a function named `f2` which takes no argument and returns an object of type `Foo`

Also consider a case when you also have a copy constructor inside `Foo`

```
Foo (const Foo& obj)     
{     
     cout << "Copy c-tor Foo()"  << endl;    
}
```

If you try writing `Foo obj(Foo())`, in this case you are likely to expect a call to the copy c-tor which would not be correct.

In that case `obj` would be parsed as a function returning a Foo object and taking an argument of type pointer to function. This is also known as **Most Vexing Parse**.

As mentioned in one of the comments `Foo obj((Foo()));` would make the compiler parse it as an expression (i.e interpret it as an object) and not a function because of the extra `()`.

Comment: Might as well mention `Foo obj((Foo()))`, would make the compiler interpret it as an object rather than a function.

Comment: In simple terms, if parameter(s) are types, compiler would treat it as function prototype. Here `()` is actually `(void)`, where `void` is a type, and not an argument.

Answer (score 4):

You are actually declaring f2 as a function that takes no parameters and returns a Foo.

Comment: I thought methods couldn't be declared inside methods, that they could only be declared within classes.

Comment: It isn't declaring a method.  It is declaring a non-member function.

Comment: You can't define it within a function, but you can declare it. You wanted just "Foo f2;"