# Can't getline() from istringstream (C++)

Tags: c++, string, iostream, stringstream

I have a previously declared `char c[64];` and I'm trying to look at the first word of the output of a pipe:

```
read(pipe_replacement_to_main[READ_END], c, BUF_SIZE);
istringstream response_stream(string(c));
string response_string;
getline(response_stream, response_string, ' ');
```

And gcc gives me the following at that fourth line:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::istringstream (&)(std::string), std::string&, char)’
```

I can't even figure out how it's trying to call the function. Did I declare the istringstream wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no), add a pair of parenthesis inside the constructor of `response_stream`.

```
istringstream response_stream((string(c)));
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice demonstration of the true "power" of C++.

The way you declared the `response_stream` variable, it is actually a function rather than type `istringstream`.