# c++, object created on the heap vs. local - when returning a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory

This is a follow up question from 
[Safe in C# not in C++, simple return of pointer / reference,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456335/safe-in-c-sharp-not-in-c-simple-return-of-pointer-reference)

Is this:

```
person* NewPerson(void)
{
  person p;
  /* ... */
  return &p; //return pointer to person.
}
```

the same as?

```
person* NewPerson(void)
{
  person* pp = new person;

  return pp; //return pointer to person.
}
```

I know that the first one is a bad idea, because it will be a wild pointer.
In the second case, will the object be safe on the heap - and like in c#
go out of scope when the last reference is gone to it?

Comment: neither of these is C# code. The second one is a memory leak in C++ if you don't manually release it.

Comment: They're not the same, and both are a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe, the object will still be alive after the return.

But don't expect the object to be automatically cleaned up for you in C++. Standard C++ does not have garbage collection. You'll need to `delete` the object yourself, or use some form of smart pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the second case is safe.

But the caller will need to `delete` the returned pointer. You could change this to use `boost::shared_ptr` and it will be destroyed when it is no longer in use:

```
boost::shared_ptr<person> NewPerson()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<person> pp = boost::make_shared<person>();

    return pp;
}
```

If C++11 then you can use `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: ok if the referenced pointers is set to 0 (null)? Or out of scope, like in c#

Comment: If it goes out of scope or you set to NULL by calling `reset()` on the returned smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> person* NewPerson(void)
> {
>   person* pp = new person;
>
>   return pp; //return pointer to person.
> }
> ```
>
> I know that the first one is a bad idea, because it will be a wild
>   pointer. In the second case, will the object be safe on the heap - and
>   like in c# go out of scope when the last reference is gone to it?

Correct on the first one: it would be returning a pointer to data on that functin's stack, which will be reclaimed and modified once the function finishes.

On the second case: the object is created on the heap, which is separate from the execution stack.  When the function finishes, the object on the heap is safe and stays the same.  However, C++ does not automatically do garbage collection, so if you lost all of the references to a heap object, this would constitute a memory leak--the object's space would not be reclaimed until the program ended.

Answer (score 0):

The latter is safe.  However, C++ does not (usually) provide garbage-collection, and thus you need to arrange for an explicit `delete` of the returned object.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, the first case is bad as the pointer will not be valid. As for the second case, memory in C++ is not managed, you have to clean up after yourself. C++ doesn't keep track of references on normal pointer, that's what [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is for.