# What is a "rooted reference"?

Tags: c#, reference, clr

Quote from ( [Safe in C# not in C++, simple return of pointer / reference,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456335/safe-in-c-sharp-not-in-c-simple-return-of-pointer-reference)  answer 3) by Eric lippert.

> Also, note that it is not any reference to the Person object that keeps it alive. The reference has to be rooted. You could have two Person objects that reference each other but are otherwise unreachable; the fact that each has a reference does not keep them alive; one  of the references has to be rooted.

I dont understand, can someone explain what a rooted reference is?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It means a GC root.

Have a read through [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/), maybe it will help with your understanding:

> GC roots are not objects in themselves but are instead references to objects. Any object referenced by a GC root will automatically survive the next garbage collection. There are four main kinds of root in .NET:
>
> A **local variable in a method that is currently running** is considered to be a GC root. The objects referenced by these variables can always be accessed immediately by the method they are declared in, and so they must be kept around. The lifetime of these roots can depend on the way the program was built. In debug builds, a local variable lasts for as long as the method is on the stack. In release builds, the JIT is able to look at the program structure to work out the last point within the execution that a variable can be used by the method and will discard it when it is no longer required. This strategy isn’t always used and can be turned off, for example, by running the program in a debugger.
>
> **Static variables** are also always considered GC roots. The objects they reference can be accessed at any time by the class that declared them (or the rest of the program if they are public), so .NET will always keep them around. Variables declared as ‘thread static’ will only last for as long as that thread is running.
>
> If **a managed object is passed to an unmanaged COM+ library through interop**, then it will also become a GC root with a reference count. This is because COM+ doesn’t do garbage collection: It uses, instead, a reference counting system; once the COM+ library finishes with the object by setting the reference count to 0 it ceases to be a GC root and can be collected again.
>
> If **an object has a finalizer**, it is not immediately removed when the garbage collector decides it is no longer ‘live’. Instead, it becomes a special kind of root until .NET has called the finalizer method. This means that these objects usually require more than one garbage collection to be removed from memory, as they will survive the first time they are found to be unused.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 11):

There're all kinds of root objects, like CLR internal objects, metadata objects, etc. This [post may help](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/net_type_internals.aspx#6):

> ### Variables and GC Roots
>
> - A variable of a Value Type is direct representation of the address of the Value Type instance on stack
> - A reference variable to a Value Type instance is called Managed Pointer and is a pointer to the starting address of the Value Type instance on stack
> - A variable of a Reference Type (UDT, Array, String, Delegate and Interface type variables) is a pointer to the Reference Type instance created on GC heap
> - CPU registers can contain Managed Pointers or Object References
> - AppDomain wide Handle tables contain GC handles that are pointers to the pinned Reference Type instances in memory. These Handle tables also contain Managed Pointers (or Object References?) to the static Value Type instances and Object References to the static Reference Type instances
> - Thread Local Storage (TLS) can contain Object References
> - FReachable Queue contains Object References of the Reference Types that are NOT referenced by any of the above variable types and for which finalize method call is pending
>
> CLR's Garbage Collector uses the above variables, also called GC roots, to track down the Object References during garbage collection phase. Any Reference Type instance located in GC heap, for which there is no Object Reference in any of the above variable types (except for the FReachable Queue), is considered a candidate for garbage collection and is removed from GC heap. If the Reference Type instance being removed implements the Finalize method, then the Object Reference is put on FReachable Queue for calling the Finalize method by a separate Finalizer thread. Once the Finalizer thread completes Finalize method call on an Object Reference, the corresponding Reference Type instance is removed from the GC heap.

Answer (score 1):

A root is a storage location, such as local variable, that could contain a reference and is known to have been initialized, and that your program use at some point in the future without needing to go via some other object reference.

In ***Programming C# 10.0*** by **Ian Griffiths** in the seventh chapter it is stated that:

> A root is a storage location, such as a local
> variable, that could contain a reference and is known to have been
> initialized, and that your program could use at some point in the future
> without needing to go via some other object reference. Not all storage
> locations are considered to be roots. If an object contains an instance field
> of some reference type, that field is not a root, because before you can use
> it, you’d need to get hold of a reference to the containing object, and it’s
> possible that the object itself is not reachable. However, a reference type
> static field is a root reference, because the program can read the value in
> that field at any time.

additionally in **[this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals)** by **Microsoft** it is said that:

> An application's roots include static fields, local variables on a thread's stack, CPU registers, GC handles, and the finalize queue. Each root either refers to an object on the managed heap or is set to null. The garbage collector can ask the rest of the runtime for these roots. The garbage collector uses this list to create a graph that contains all the objects that are reachable from the roots.

According to ***C# 12 in a Nutshell*** by **Joseph Albahari**, Root A root is something that keeps an object alive. If an object is not directly or indirectly referenced by a root, it will be eligible for garbage collection.

The figure below from the same book can help in understanding:
[image]