# What makes a form stay as an rooted reference?

Tags: c#, reference, clr

Follow up question from [What is a "rooted reference"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458886/what-is-a-rooted-reference)

consider this code, for a standard windows application in c#:

Program.cs:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        finally
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Bye !");
        }
    }
```

From1.cs:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Click += new EventHandler(Form1_Click);

    }

    void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

What makes this form to stay as an rooted reference?
Is it because of the Static Main method, i guess it is,
or is it anything more to it?

If i just close the form with the X, then the message box will show "bye",
but not if i click it. (because of the application.Exit()) - and i think
that is strange consider the  finally method in main.

So the main question, what makes the form object, stay as an rooted reference so the carbage collector not will kill it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Application.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx) method doesn't terminate until your form closes. You pass in your instance of `Form1` as a parameter to `Run` and it becomes *a local variable in a method that is currently running*, and therefore a root.

Internally `Application.Run` actually creates an [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z3x9h60.aspx) which holds the reference to the form:

```
public class ApplicationContext : IDisposable
{
    public Form MainForm
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
        set { /* ... */ }
    }

    public ApplicationContext(Form mainForm)
    {
        this.MainForm = mainForm;
    }

    // ...
}
```

The `ApplicationContext` is then given to the `RunMessageLoop` method.

Comment: To clarify to the OP - the `ApplicationContext` is rooted, not the form.

Answer (score 2):

What roots the instance of `Form1` is that if you follow all of the referencing objects back, you will eventually find a reference in a static variable (which is a rooted reference). To follow the path back to the rooted reference:

- The `Form1` instance is stored in an instance field on a newly constructed `ApplicationContext` instance.
- That `ApplicationContext` instance is stored as an instance field on a `ThreadContext` instance.
- That `ThreadContext` instance is stored in a static variable on `ThreadContext` class <-- ROOTED REFERNCE

Comment: True but overcomplicated. in `Foo(new Bar())` the Bar instance is _reachable_ for as long as Foo  executes.  Simply by being on the stack.