# Prevent object from getting garbage collected

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Inside a console app I have the following code:

```
    private static System.Timers.Timer TaskTimer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //run each minute
        Func<double> getNextMinute = () => { return (DateTime.Now.RoundUp(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds; };
        TaskTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(getNextMinute());
        TaskTimer.AutoReset = false;
        TaskTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            TaskTimer.Interval = getNextMinute();
            TaskTimerCallback();
        };
        TaskTimer.Start();

        bool exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            exit = (command == "exit");
        }
    }
```

If I check the timers GC generation, it's always 0.

Is there any chance that the TaskTimerObject will get garbage collected before a tick?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance that timer can get garbage collected before the tick.

Comment: You can use `GC.KeepAlive` I think

Comment: No, as it's `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, the GC won't collect the TaskTimerObject.

the field TaskTimer is a [Root Referance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458886/what-is-a-rooted-reference) which points to TaskTimerObject.