# .Net Garbage Collection on LoH

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

When the memory dump is being analyzed, it shows that this particular string variable which is holding the xml content is causing memory leak. I read on some of the articles that LoH goes to Gen 2. So,

1. Will garbage collector gets invoked if Gen 0 and Gen 1 is not under pressure and Gen 2 is under pressure due to LoH ?
2. Will it go to Gen 2 when it has released Gen 0 or Gen 1 memory ?
3. If so what’s the better way to handle this ?

Comment: Is LoH the Large Object Heap? Do include the framework version for questions involving the GC and attempts made to find out more information on this.

Comment: Do include a link to the article you read as well

Comment: Is there a reference to that string? Is it perhaps interned?

Comment: Tried on all .Net versions from 2.0 to 4.6. The instance that holds this string has been set of null also.

Comment: It is not that simple, a program that *only* allocates large objects (>= 85000 bytes) still runs the garbage collector even though it only ever allocates LOH objects.  Clearly the info you provided does not give anybody a decent shot at guessing why this large string isn't getting collected, you'll have to work on repro code.

Comment: Get a memory profiler designed for .NET and see what holds this string in memory

Answer (score 0):

1. No, it will not
2. Only if there's enough memory pressure

However, if your application is doing allocations, it's pretty unlikely the string will survive for too long. And if there's not enough memory pressure, the GC has little reason to release the memory.

Do make sure the string is not referenced anymore, though. Count the references, check that it's not interned.

You can force a garbage collection, but it's great way to damage GC performance. It might be the best solution for your case if your application does the odd "allocate a huge string and then forget it" operation, *and* you care about memory available to the rest of the system (there's no benefit to *your* application). There's no point in trying that if you're doing a lot of allocations anyway, though - in that case, look for memory leaks on your side. WinDbg can help.

Comment: I have used WinDbg to analyze.
1. String is not interned.

Comment: Slight modification to my Question 1 
Will garbage collector gets invoked if Gen 0 and Gen 1 is not under pressure and Gen 2 is under pressure due to LoH ?

Comment: @SudheeshP There's no such thing, so no, it will not. That's kind of the point of having the generational heaps in the first place. And AFAIK, the limits (and allocation thresholds) for each of the generations increase if you require a lot of memory overall, though I'm not sure if this also applies for "one big thing on LOH". In the end, avoiding allocating such a huge string might be your best approach anyway (most APIs allow for streaming). Also, why do you care if the memory is released? Are you having issues, or are you just scared of the big number in task manager?

Comment: The memory grows and finally the application crashes

Comment: @SudheeshP Okay, so the string must be referenced somewhere (unless you're simply trying to allocate a string that has no place to go - like a 2 GiB string or something in a 32-bit process). How did you check there are no references to the string?

Comment: @SudheeshP And there are no roots at all? Are you using the full memory dump? And when you check after the next operation (e.g. the next file processing), the original string still remains? Do you have a dump from the crash? Have you checked the heap fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

*1. Will garbage collector gets invoked if Gen 0 and Gen 1 is not under pressure ?*
If there is enough space in `Generation0` and `Generation2`, then Garbage Collector will not be invoked.

If there is enough space in `Generation0` and `Generation2`, then it means that that there is enough space to create new objects and there is no reason to run Garabage Collection.

*2. Will it go to Gen 2 when it has released Gen 0 or Gen 1 memory ?*

If the object is survived after Garbage Collection in `Generation1` and in the `Generation1`, then the object will be moved to `Generation2`.

*3. If so what’s the better way to handle this ?*

- To destroy an object from heap, you should just delete references of this string. Your `string` variable which has xml values should not be `static` to be garbage collected.([read more about roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458886/what-is-a-rooted-reference))
- Try to use compact `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`:

  GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode = GCLargeObjectHeapCompactionMode.CompactOnce;
  GC.Collect();

This will compact the Large Object Heap when the next `Full Garbage Collection` is executed. With `GC.Collect()` call after the settings been applied, the GC gets compacted immediately.

- Try to use `WeakReference`:

  `WeakReference w = new WeakReference(MyLargeObject);
   MyLargeObject = w.Target as MyLargeClass;`

  `MyLargeClass MyLargeObject;

  if ( (w == null) || ( (MyLargeObject=w.Target as MyLargeClass) == null) )
  {
      MyLargeObject = new MyLargeClass();
      w = new WeakReference(MyLargeObject);
  }`

This article gives is very useful to you about [`Garbage Collection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx) and the article is written in plain English.

Comment: This was the last thing i tried, the memory gets released, but it is badly affecting the performance.

Comment: @SudheeshP try to use `WeakReference`. Please, see my updated section