# asp.net core 2.1 dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

In a asp.net core 2.1 MVC application I have the following code coming a bit from a Github from a nugget and some addition made by me :

```
    public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<TUser, TRole>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupIdentityAction, Action<MongoIdentityOptions> setupDatabaseAction) where TUser : UserEntity where TRole : RoleEntity
    {
        services.AddIdentity<TUser, TRole>(setupIdentityAction ?? (x => { }))
            .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<TRole>>()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<TUser, TRole>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        var dbOptions = new MongoIdentityOptions();
        setupDatabaseAction(dbOptions);

        var userCollection = new IdentityUserCollection<TUser>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString);
        var roleCollection = new IdentityRoleCollection<TRole>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString);

        // Add collections and stores in services for DI
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityUserCollection<TUser>>(x => userCollection);
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityRoleCollection<TRole>>(x => roleCollection);

        services.AddTransient<ITenantStore<TenantEntity, TUser>>(x => new TenantStore<TenantEntity, TUser>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString, userCollection));
        services.AddTransient<ILicenseStore<LicenseEntity>>(x => new LicenseStore<LicenseEntity>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString));

        // Identity Services
        services.AddTransient((Func<IServiceProvider, IUserStore<TUser>>)(x => new UserStore<TUser, TRole>(userCollection, roleCollection, x.GetService<ILookupNormalizer>())));
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<TRole>>(x => new RoleStore<TRole>(roleCollection));

        return services;
    }
```

So as you can see it's using the dependency injection, but i'm asking myself somes questions :

1) the userCollection and roleCollection are 'local' variable that are then passed into DI. But then how is the lifecycle of those object managed? I mean are they never disposed because they are used in DI? Or are they creating each time?

2) Is there a difference between

```
services.AddTransient<ILicenseStore<LicenseEntity>>(x => new LicenseStore<LicenseEntity>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString));
```

And

```
services.AddTransient<ILicenseStore<LicenseEntity>>(new LicenseStore<LicenseEntity>(dbOptions.DbType, dbOptions.ConnectionString));
```

3) In the line

```
services.AddTransient((Func<IServiceProvider, IUserStore<TUser>>)(x => new UserStore<TUser, TRole>(userCollection, roleCollection, x.GetService<ILookupNormalizer>())));
```

There is the 'x.GetService()'. Is that a way to tell the constructor that the parameter needed in the constructor will be from DI? Sort of using Dependency Injection in DependecyInjection?

4) In case of yes to question 3, is it possible to do something like this?

```
services.AddSingletion<IMongoClient>(new MongoClient("connectionString"));
services.AddTransient<IXStore>(new XStore(x.GetService<IMongoClient>()))
```

The point being to achieve that the MongoClient will be a singleton (which is the recommended way)

5) What is the difference beetween :

```
services.AddScoped((Func<IServiceProvider, IUserStore<TUser>>)(x => new UserStore<TUser, TRole>(x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityUserCollection<TUser>>(), x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityRoleCollection<TRole>>(), x.GetService<ILookupNormalizer>())));
```

And

```
services.AddScoped<IUserStore<TUser>, UserStore<TUser, TRole>>();
```

Thanks a lot for the answers :)

**Edit:**

New way:

```
        services.AddSingleton<ICustomMongoClient>(x => new CustomMongoClient(dbOptions.ConnectionString));

        // Add collections and stores in services for DI
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityUserCollection<TUser>>(x => new IdentityUserCollection<TUser>(x.GetRequiredService<ICustomMongoClient>()));
        services.AddTransient<IIdentityRoleCollection<TRole>>(x => new IdentityRoleCollection<TRole>(x.GetRequiredService<ICustomMongoClient>()));


        services.AddTransient<ITenantStore<TenantEntity, TUser>>(x => new TenantStore<TenantEntity, TUser>(x.GetRequiredService<ICustomMongoClient>(), x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityUserCollection<TUser>>()));
        services.AddTransient<ILicenseStore<LicenseEntity>>(x => new LicenseStore<LicenseEntity>(x.GetRequiredService<ICustomMongoClient>()));

        // Identity Services
        services.AddTransient((Func<IServiceProvider, IUserStore<TUser>>)(x => new UserStore<TUser, TRole>(x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityUserCollection<TUser>>(), x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityRoleCollection<TRole>>(), x.GetService<ILookupNormalizer>())));
        services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<TRole>>(x => new RoleStore<TRole>(x.GetRequiredService<IIdentityRoleCollection<TRole>>()));
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all `userCollection` and `roleCollection` are instantiated only once. Both of these local variables won't be garbage collected for the following reason. They are captured by delegates created with lambdas (`x => userCollection` and `x => roleCollection`) and the delegates are added to services collection which is definitely a [GC root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8458890/7775908).
2. Yes, there is. First line compiles and latter one doesn't. You can pass constructed object only to `AddSingleton`. The only difference between `services.AddSingleton(x => new object)` and `services.AddSingleton(new object)` is when the object is instantiated, right now (`new object`) or at the first request to specified service type (`x => new object`).
3. Yes.
4. If you fix second line
   `services.AddSingletion<IMongoClient>(new MongoClient("connectionString"));` `services.AddTransient<IXStore>(x => new XStore(x.GetService<IMongoClient>()))`
   then answer is *Yes*. In fact *DI* container does this for you, calls `GetService` for every constructor parameter. So the following code is equivalent to yours
   `services.AddSingletion<IMongoClient>(new MongoClient("connectionString"));`
   `services.AddTransient<IXStore, XStore>()`
5. Basically both examples are the same. When you use first example you manually resolving all constructor parameters using `DI` container. Whe you use second one the `DI` container resolves all constructor parameters automatically for you. So prefer second approach in this case, because it is less code. Consider using first approach only when you need instantiate objects by yourself using `new` or providing them with some other services and not by `DI` container.

Comment: First thanks for the response, it's helping me a lot :)

Comment: First thanks for the response, it's helping me a lot :)

Getting back to point 1:
Correct me if i'm wrong but the fact that `userCollection ` and `roleCollection ` are GC root is not a good think (or at leat not neccessary). So a better solution will be to resolve the collections using DI?

What is according to you the better solution?

(second comment because of 5 minutes rule, sorry)

Comment: I've got some time to rethink the way it was done.
I edited my question with a new way of doing it, can I have your opinion on it please?
Thanks

Comment: @S.Martignier It looks okay, but I need to know more about the nature of classes and so on to say more precise things, so I'll leave my opinion based on what I've seen. I believe it's better to have `Scoped` lifetime for all `Stores` because access to them is usually transactional so you would like to have the same `Store` instance per request. And you can write it shorter just by calling `services.AddTransient<IType, Type>()`. And you can only used predefined types in generics, `AddTransient<IUser<T>, User<T>>` is wrong because there is no such type `T`, (IUser<UserM>, User<UserM>) is fine

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
The TUser and TRole looks like generic indeed but they are not, it's because those services calls are inside an extension method that looks like :
`public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<TUser, TRole>(this IServiceCollection services, Action<IdentityOptions> setupIdentityAction, Action<MongoIdentityOptions> setupDatabaseAction) where TUser : UserEntity where TRole : RoleEntity`

Can I ask you one last thing (question 5 in question post)?

Comment: @S.Martignier Updated my answer with 5th question info

Comment: Big big thanks for all yours answers, it's really helped me to understand DI better and to produces better code