# C++ spooky constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Lets have this code

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int) { }
};
```

Then we have there results:

```
int main() {
  Foo f1 = Foo(5); // 1: OK, explicit call
  Foo f2(5); // 2: OK, implicit call
  Foo f3(); // 3: no error, "f3 is a non-class type Foo()", how so?
  Foo f4(f1); // 4: OK, implicit call to default copy constructor
  Foo f5; // 5: expected error: empty constructor missing
}
```

Can you explain what's happening in case **3**?

Comment: search: vexing parse

Comment: @Nim: Should have been an answer.

Comment: Also note that example 5 is doing what expected example 3 to do and calls the default constructor.

Comment: @BjörnPollex, recently, I've taken up commenting with appropriate search terms - sometimes, it's just a matter of missing terminology, and the OP can then discover for themselves.. :) anyways, I knew someone would come in quicker with a real answer.. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Foo f3();` declares a function called `f3`, with a return type of `Foo`.

Comment: Ah, of course! I was so focused on constructors...

Answer (score 12):

The third line is parsed as declaring a function that takes no argument and returns a `Foo`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has a rule that if a statement can be interpreted as a function declaration, it is interpreted in this way.

Hence the syntax `Foo f3();` actually declares a function which takes no arguments and returns  `Foo`. Work this around by writing `Foo f3;`, it will call the default constructor too (if there is one, of course).

Answer (score 4):

- `f1` invokes the copy constructor after an explicit call, you were wrong on this one
- `f2` is an explicit constructor call // you were wrong here too
- `f3` declares a function
- `f4` is again the copy constructor, like `f1` // you're right here
- `f5` would calls the default constructor // you're right here again

Comment: `Foo f6 = 5;` would by an implicit constructor call? IIRC.

Comment: @Douglas: Yes, that would be correct.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't what you think it is:

```
 Foo f3();
```

You may think this is an explicit call of the default constructor, but it's not.  It's actually a declaration of a function named `f3` which takes no parameters and returns a `Foo` by value.

That this is parsed as a function declaration rather than a constructor call is known as the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: No it's not. The MVP is when you provide arguments and it still looks like a function declaration. This is not the MVP it's just the programmer being silly

Answer (score 2):

You've defined a function called f3 that returns a foo in case 3.  In case 5, you have no default constructor defined, so you get an error.