# Why doesn't "foo f();" call the constructor of a class "foo"?

Tags: c++, constructor, execution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

I bumped into the following problem. I created 2 instances of foo.
Then I realized, that `foo f();` didn't execute the contructor of a class. Why is that?

```
class foo{
public:
    foo() {cout <<"executed contructor...";}
};

int main() {
    foo f(); // doesn't run the ctor???? why?
    foo f2; // this one does execute the ctor


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See this previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no

Comment: `foo f3(foo());` is an example of the most vexing parse. `foo f();` is just a slightly vexing parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first declares a function. Try to access the object named `f`. The compiler will complain along the lines: f has non class type `foo ()`, which means it is a function taking no arguments and returning an object of type `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Check C++ FAQ question 10.2:

> [10.2] Is there any difference between List x; and List x();?

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2