# difference between A aaa; and A aaa();

Tags: c++, object, syntax, declaration

```
class A{
    private:
        string a;
    public:
        A():a("hello world"){};
        A(const string & arg):a(arg){};
        void put()const{cout<<a;};
};

A aaa();
A bbb;
```

So what's the difference between `A aaa();` and `A bbb;` Is `aaa` a function?

Comment: there is a 3rd option. calling constructor explicitly. A aaa = A();

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, the first one is interpreted as a function declaration. It's been called the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: `A aaa();` is not an example of the "most vexing parse". The most vexing parse refers to when you try to delcare an object and pass a value initializer temporary to all of its constructor parameters. e.g. `B c(D());`