# Why is the constructor not called when () is used to declare an object?

Tags: c++, constructor, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

```
$ cat cons.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Matrix {
private:
    int m_count;

public:
    Matrix() {
        m_count = 1;
        std::cout << "yahoo!" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    Matrix m1();                         // <----
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
$ g++ cons.cpp
$ ./a.out
before
after
$
```

**What does the syntax `Matrix m1();` do?**

I believed that it is the same as `Matrix m1;`. Obviously I am wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Matrix m1(); // m1 is a function whose return type is Matrix.
```

Also this C++ FAQ lite entry should be helpful.

[Is there any difference between List x; and List x();](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2)

Comment: @Lazer: to convince yourself, try to use m1 (for example accessing m1.m_count )...

Comment: In C++11 you can use braces for all constructor calls this avoids c++'s most  vexing parse i.e Matrix m1{};

Comment: This isn't the "most vexing parse", the most vexing parse is when you try to declare and object and pass a value initialized temporary to one or more of it's constructor parameters. E.g. `A b(A());`. `Matrix m1();` is just a regular function declaration.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: the Most Vexing Parse is about treating a declaration as a function declaration if at all possible. This question is indeed just yet another Most Vexing Parse question.

Answer (score 3):

`Matrix m1()` declares a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Matrix`.  You can see this is so by adding a method to `Matrix` and trying to invoke it on `m1`:

```
#include <iostream>

class Matrix {
private:
    int m_count;

public:
    Matrix() {
        m_count = 1;
        std::cout << "yahoo!" << std::endl;
    }
    void foo() {}
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    Matrix m1();
    m1.foo();
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

gives `error: request for member 'foo' in 'm1', which is of non-class type 'Matrix()'`

Answer (score 1):

Think from C language perspective:

```
int data_member();
```

is actually a prototype for function taking void and returning int. When you change it like:

```
T data();
```

it still is a function declaration, retuning `T`. When you need to declare it as variable, you do:

```
T data; // int data;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're trying to do:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
    Matrix m1;                         // <----
    std::cout << "after" << std::endl;
}
```

In C++, if you initialize a variable with parens, it actually declares a function that takes no parameters and returns that type.