# C++ exception doesn't get thrown for default constructor?

Tags: c++, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

I have a very simple C++ class "A", whose empty constructor is invoked in main.  The one and only empty c'tor just throws an exception **SomeException**.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class SomeException : public exception { };


class A {

public:
    A() {
        throw SomeException();
    }

};

int main() {
    try {
        //A a();
        A a;
        cout << "No exception." << endl;
    }
    catch (SomeException& se) {
        cout << "Caught se." << endl;
    }
}
```

When I invoke A's constructor with no parantheses like below, it correctly throws the intended exception.

```
A a;
```

The output in this case is:

```
$ ./a.exe
Caught se.
```

But if I invoke the c'tor with the below syntax, it doesn't throw exception, and continues to next line, as though nothing happened!

```
A a();
```

The output in this case is...

```
$ ./a.exe
No exception.
```

I tried the above program on Ubuntu 11.10 and also on windows usign minGW, and both give identical results.  I am using GCC version 4.5.2 for minGW and 4.6.1 for Ubuntu.

Any clues about this strange behavior?  Is this a bug in gcc, or is my way is incorrect?

Comment: You have just discovered [the most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)!

Comment: My bad.  I should have invoked it  as
A a = A(); instead of A a();  Though the program compiles with the later declaration, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanx Martinho, I am reading your link..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
A a();
```

is a function declaration, not an object instantiation. No object is constructed, no constructor is called, no exception thrown.

It's called **most vexing parse**.

It's not a bug, it's perfectly fine.

These two:

```
A a();
A b;
```

are not equivalent. The second creates an object of type `A` called `b`. The first declares a method called `a` that takes no arguments and returns `A`.