# C++ inheritance error when object is allocated on the stack

Tags: c++, inheritance, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

I have small code sample:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:

  void print()
  {
     cout << "Hello" << endl;
  }

};

class B: public A
{

  public:

  B() { cout << "Creating B" << endl;}

};


int main()
{

  B b();

  b.print(); // error: request for member ‘print’ in ‘b’, which is of non-class type ‘B ()()’



}
```

However if I change to the one below, if it works,

```
B* b = new B();

b->print();
```

Why doesn't it work when I allocate the object on the stack ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `B b();` declares a function named `b` that returns a `B`. Just use `B b;` and blame the fact that C++ has a complex grammar that makes this sort of construct tricky.

Answer (score 4):

`B b();` declares a function named `b` that takes nothing and returns `B`. Surprising? Try to rename your class `B` as `Int`, and name your "object" `f`. Now it looks like

```
Int f();
```

looks more like a function, doesn't it?

To define a default-constructed object, you need:

```
B b;
```

In case of `operator new`, the default constructor can be called with or without parentheses:

```
B* b = new B;
B* b = new B();
```