# Why do I need double parentheses  in constructor calls like: foo x( (bar()) );

Tags: c++, compiler-theory, most-vexing-parse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

I have seen the [C++ FQA](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.19) [entries](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/fn-decl-vs-obj-instantiation.html) about nested constructor calls and bracing and always wondered how C++ parsers resolve two and why it isn't possible for parsers to resolve it.

So I get why `foo xxx();` is ambiguous. but what makes then `foo x(bar());` ambiguous, as it is clearly no forward-declaration. (i.e.: there should be a grammar that can successfully detect this).

Could someone explain the limitations and ambiguity in that part of the C++ grammar?

Comment: google "most vexing parse"

Comment: The FAQ entry you linked explains that. Third paragraph from bottom.

Comment: These are braces: `{}`. These are parentheses: `()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
foo x(bar());
```

This could be either:

1) A declaration for a variable called `x` whose value is a default-constructed `bar`. This is the same as `foo x = bar();`.

2) A declaration for a function called `x` that returns `foo` and takes a single parameter -- a function that returns a `bar` and takes no parameters. This is the same as `foo x(bar (void));`

Comment: that is my point here isn't 2 an invalid declaration? or what does it mean? does it mean then that bar is a function prototype and foo takes a function pointer as first argument? shouldn't that be bar (*)() then?

Comment: No, 2 isn't an invalid declaration. `foo x(bar (void))` means that `x` is a function that returns `foo` and takes `bar (*)(void)`. The reason the `(*)` doesn't have to be explicit is that there's a rule for function declarations that if a parameter type is a function type then the parameter is 'adjusted' to be a pointer to that function type. This is exactly like the rule where if a parameter is an array it is 'adjusted' to be a pointer type; `void a(int x[])` is exactly equivalent to `void a(int *x)`, and `foo x(bar())` is equivalent to `foo x(bar(*)())`.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ FQA is a pile of garbage. Ignore it.

As for `foo x(bar())`, it is as ambiguous as `foo x()`, except the type of `x` also takes an argument, which is a function. Add a pointer here and you'll see what I mean.

```
foo (*x)();
foo (*x)(bar(*)());
```

Even the idea of allowing this is beyond silly, but nobody can change it now.

(I have a sneaking suspicion that this grammar is a tad off, but I'm sure someone will correct me).

Comment: I don't think `x` is a function pointer here, just a function declaration that decays to a pointer when used.

Comment: It isn't, I'm just adding the pointer to make it more obvious how it's equivalent.