# Can't call default constructor explicitly

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error on calling default constructor with empty set of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/error-on-calling-default-constructor-with-empty-set-of-brackets)

Why does the following code compile without problems but when I switch the line

```
MCl<char, a> tryout;
```

to

```
MCl<char, a> tryout();
```

I receive "error C2228: left of '.ea' must have class/struct/union" ? Isn't tryout() a call to the default constructor?

Here's the full code

```
template <class T, T myval> class MCl
{
public:
    T ea;
    MCl() : ea(myval)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{


    const char a = 'e';
    MCl<char, a> tryout;
    // MCl<char, a> tryout();

    cout << tryout.ea;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See [most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MCl<char, a> tryout();
```

declares function tryout, that receives nothing and returns `MCl<char, a>`.

n3337 8.2/1

> the choice is between a **function declaration
> with a redundant set of parentheses around a parameter name and an object declaration with a function-style
> cast as the initializer. Just as for the ambiguities mentioned in 6.8, the resolution is to consider any construct
> that could possibly be a declaration a declaration.** [ Note: A declaration can be explicitly disambiguated by
> a nonfunction-style cast, by an = to indicate initialization or by removing the redundant parentheses around
> the parameter name. —end note ]

Answer (score 4):

```
MCl<char, a> tryout();
```

This is ambiguous as either a function prototype or instantiation through a void constructor. This ambiguity has been covered to death as 'the most vexing parse' - it is even discussed in the C++03 standard itself!

However, people tend not to mention that C++11 introduces a new syntax to disambiguate this through uniform initialization. Under this new syntax, your instantiation of `MCl` would be expressed as so:

```
MCl<char, a> tryout{};
```

Answer (score 0):

Declares a variables;

```
MCl<char, a> tryout;    // uses default constructor if user defined one.
                        // If compiler generated constructor uses value-initialized
                        // of members which for POD types means uninitialized.
```

Is a forward declaration to a function (called tryout):

```
MCl<char, a> tryout();
```

What you wanted was probably: (for C++03 for C++11 see Mike Kwan).

```
MCl<char, a> tryout  = MCl<char, a>(); // uses default constructor if user defined one.
                        // If compiler generated constructor uses zero-initialized
                        // of members which for POD types means 0 is placed in them.
```