# copy constructor strange compile error

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
namespace js0n
{

struct json
{
  typedef int json_object;

  json(){}

  json(json_object const& other)
  {
  }

  json& operator=(json_object const& other)
  {
    return *this;
  }
};

typedef json::json_object json_object;

}
```

The line `js0n::json json(js0n::json_object());` gives a compile error.

```
int main()
{
  js0n::json json(js0n::json_object());

  return 0;
}
```

Note that I've culled away much of the code, as it is not responsible for the error. What am I doing wrong?

The error message:

```
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:9:8: error: request for member 'parse' in 'json', which is of non-class type     'js0n::json(js0n::json_object (*)()) {aka js0n::json(int (*)())}'
```

The assignment operators i.e. (`json = json_object();`) is working just fine.

Comment: Way.Too.Much.Code. Please cull away *anything* unnecessary and include the error you get.

Comment: You can disregard much of it. The problem is with the copy constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `js0n::json json(js0n::json_object());`

Welcome to the [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/180172/500104). This declares a function returning `js0n::json` and taking a `js0n::json_object` argument. To disambiguate, either add more parens, as suggested in the answer to that question, or (since you originally tagged this `[c++11]`), use list-initialization:

```
js0n::json json{js0n::json_object()};
```

Or

```
js0n::json json(js0n::json_object{});
```

Or

```
js0n::json json{js0n::json_object{}};
```

:)

Comment: Yeah I've tagged `c++11` because of the `std::unordered_map`. Thanks!

Comment: @user: Always tag with `[c++]` atleast, and if it's something specific about C+11, add `[c++11]`. However, your code could've been cut down to no includes at all and a 5-10 line example, really.

Comment: Cull complete, also note the `= default` alongside the default constructor, another C++11 feature.

Comment: @user: I culled it even further to drop that one too. :) Also, really, C++11 is the current standard, so the C++ tag alone suffices. Only if the question's *specifically* about a C++11 feature I'd add the C++11 tag.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't said what the compilation error is, but it looks like you've tripped over the [most vexing parse](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=767929):

```
js0n::json json(js0n::json_object());
```

This declares a function.  To declare a local variable, you need more parentheses:

```
js0n::json json((js0n::json_object()));
                ^                   ^
```