# Constructor issue

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

This is the code that I worked on and I don't understand what it's happening on constructor Package obj2(); On output are displayed only the values 4 (Package obj1(4)) and 2 (Package obj3(2))

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Package
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    Package()
    {
        cout<<"constructor #1"<<endl;
        value = 7; cout << value << endl;

    }
    Package(int v)
    {
        cout<<"constructor #2"<<endl;
        value = v; cout << value << endl;

    }
    ~Package()
    {
        cout<<"destructor"<<endl;
        cout << value << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Package obj1(4);
    Package obj2();
    Package obj3(2);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line

```
Package obj2();
```

needs to be

```
Package obj2;
```

More info

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/empty-parens-in-object-decl.html

or, alternative take on this (from Google cache, real site was down, and take it with a grain of salt, it raises good points but does its best to make them sound worse than they are):

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://yosefk.com/c%2B%2Bfqa/ctors.html#fqa-10.2

Comment: I gave the reason, you gave the fix!

Comment: Don't need `()` when calling default contructor

Comment: @EmmanuelN it's not just "don't need", it's "must not use".

Comment: So how does he initialize the constructor parameter?

Comment: @David default constructor call does not, by definition, have any parameters (default constructor can take parsmeters though, as long as all have default value).

Answer (score 8):

This does not declare an object:

```
Package obj2();
```

Believe it or not, it declares a function that returns a `Package` object. It's called "the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)."

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C++11, and want to solve the 'most vexing parse' problem, you can replace

```
Package obj2();
```

with

```
Package obj2{};
```

This is part of the [uniform initialization syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) of C++11, which was designed primarily to get around this problem.