# Member function as a Qt Slot

Tags: qt, function, connect, member, slot

I need to connect a button to a member function from another class. Here the class' code :

```
 int g_switch_value = 0;
int filterInt = 0;
int lastfilterInt = -1;

void MoyenEtMedian::switch_callback(int position, void* object)
{   MoyenEtMedian* moyetmed = (MoyenEtMedian*) object;
    filterInt = position;
}

void MoyenEtMedian::exec(void)
{
    const char* name = "Filtres";
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "image.png" );
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
    cvNamedWindow( name, 1 );
    cvShowImage(name, out);

    // Create trackbar
    cvCreateTrackbar2( "Filtre", name, &g_switch_value, 1, &MoyenEtMedian::switch_callback, this );

    while( 1 ) {
        switch( filterInt ){
            case 0:
                cvSmooth( img, out, CV_BLUR, 7, 7 );
                break;
            case 1:
                cvSmooth( img, out, CV_MEDIAN, 7, 7 );
                break;
                    }
        if(filterInt != lastfilterInt){
            cvShowImage(name, out);
            lastfilterInt = filterInt;
        }
        if( cvWaitKey( 15 ) == 27 )
            break;
    }

    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvReleaseImage( &out );
    cvDestroyWindow( name );
```

}

Here's the .cpp of the GUI (created with Qt Designer):

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale(QWidget *parent) :
QWidget(parent),
ui(new Ui::FenPrincipale)
{

ui->setupUi(this);


QObject::connect(ui->bMoyMed,SIGNAL(clicked()),MoyenEtMedian,SLOT(MoyenEtMedian::exec()));

}
```

I'm getting the "not declard in this scope" error for MoyenEtMedian, even when passing it directly.

**UPDATE** : #include was missing. The "not declared in this scope" issue is resolved.

But I have another one :

"expected primary-expression before ',' token"  concerning :

```
QObject::connect(ui->bMoyMed,SIGNAL(clicked()),MoyenEtMedian,SLOT(exec()));
```

I have declared the SLOT in the moyenetmedian.h file :

```
 #ifndef MOYENETMEDIAN_H
 #define MOYENETMEDIAN_H
 #include "ui_fenprincipale.h"

 class MoyenEtMedian
 {Q_OBJECT
  public:
 MoyenEtMedian();
 static void switch_callback(int position, void*);

 public slots :
 void exec(void);

 };

 #endif // MOYENETMEDIAN_H
```

Comment: The third parameter to connect should be a pointer to the receiver class. Also i don't think you need to use the class name inside the SLOT macro.

Answer (score 4):

Until Qt 5.0, the destination of a connection has to be declared as a SLOT in the class declaration.

Qt 5.0 introduced some new syntax for connection. One of them allows you to connect a signal to any member function:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect-4

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object `MoyenEtMedian` here a sample with `FenPrincipale` member (or you can pass your object as argument to the `FenPrincipale` contructor if it was already created).

```
FenPrincipale::FenPrincipale(QWidget *parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::FenPrincipale)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    moyenEtMedian = new MoyenEtMedian();
    QObject::connect(ui->bMoyMed,SIGNAL(clicked()), moyenEtMedian, SLOT(exec()));
}
```

In your code `MoyenEtMedian` is a class not an object.

Comment: I did this, and I got new errors : " conversion from 'MoyenEtMedian*' to non-scalar type 'MoyenEtMedian' requested"    and      "no matching function for call to 'FenPrincipale::connect(QPushButton*&, const char [11], MoyenEtMedian&, const char [8])'"

Comment: `moyenEtMedian = new MoyenEtMedian();` is an error, should be `moyenEtMedian = new MoyenEtMedian;`   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Comment: You have to declare in the `FenPrincipale` class declaration your member like this : `MoyenEtMedian *moyenEtMedian;`

Comment: Add this `class MoyenEtMedian;` before `FenPrincipale` class declaration (.h file).