# Why do I get a compile error when I explicity use the default constructor?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

Can anyone explain why I get a compile error for the following code?

```
CString CDiagram::GetFormattedMessage()
{
    CString strFormat();
    strFormat = "Warning : %s"
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared a function `strFormat` that returns type `CString`.  Whoops.  Google "C++ most vexing parse" for more literature.  Correct syntax is

```
CString strFormat;
```

Which *does* explicitly call the default constructor, unlike, say, in Java, where this would just declare a null variable without instantiating it.