# Initialize a dynamic vector list

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector

I am trying to initialize my MedList but it's not working. Here's what I'm talking about:
 repository.h

```
#include "../domain/farmacy.h"
#include "../utils/DynamicVector.h"
class Repository{

private:
    DynamicVector<Medicine>* MedList; //I made it pointer so it can be dynamic

public:
Repository(); //constructor
```

repository.cpp

```
#include "../domain/farmacy.h"
#include "repository.h"
#include "../utils/DynamicVector.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

Repository::Repository(){
    this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>::DynamicVector(); //error
}
```

DynamicVector.h

```
template <typename Element> //this is the Dynamic Vector constructor
DynamicVector<Element>::DynamicVector()
{
    this->cap=10;
    this->len=0;
    this->elems=new Element[this->cap];
}
```

the error above is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - no match for 'operator=' in '((Repository*)this)->Repository::MedList = (int*)operator 
     new(4u)'
    - expected type-specifier
    - candidate is:
    - expected ';'
```

this is the medicine class

```
class Medicine{

private:
    int ID;
    std::string nume;
    double concentratie;
    int cantitate;
```

The Dynamic Vector class:

```
template <typename Element>
class DynamicVector{

private:
    Element* elems;
    int cap;
    int len;
    void resize();
    void CopyToThis(const DynamicVector& v);

public:
    DynamicVector(); //constructor implicit
    DynamicVector(const DynamicVector& ); //constructor de copiere
    DynamicVector& operator=(const DynamicVector& );
    ~DynamicVector();
    void addElement(Element elem);
    Element delElementAtPosition(int pos);
    Element getElementAtPosition(int pos);
    int getLen();

};
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried a lot of variants but nothing seems to work. Could you help me?

Comment: can you post the dynamicVector class?

Comment: Yep you don't have a constructor delared in there. See my answer.

Comment: @stardust_ Actually, I have. I only copied what was private. Now I updated and added what is public too. The constructor is public

Comment: Well I took your code as you have written it. It compiles fine for me

Comment: I am sure it is the () issue. `this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>;` should at least change the error message.

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/2q1aBJ$4

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing c++ syntax for creating object with some other language, e.g. Java or C#.

In c++, a constructor is called simply by declaring the variable:

```
DynamicVector<Element> medList; // Calls DynamicVector<Element>::DynamicVector()
```

The `new` operator in C#, is to dynamically allocate space for a variable, and returns a *pointer to the allocated space*. To use it here, you'd have to declare Repository::MedList as a pointer type, and initialize it like so:

```
DynamicVector<Medicine>* MedList; // in repository.h

this->MedList = new DynamicVector<Medicine>(); // in repository.cpp
```

However, as Andy Prowl pointed out, it is much better to just let the compiler do the memory management for you. To do so, you should completely remove the erroneous line in `repository.cpp`. Why? Well, when the repository is constructed, the compiler also tries to construct all member objects using their default constructors. This is exactly what you want, so there is no reason to try to alter the compiler's behavior.

Comment: The spirit of this answer is correct, but the OP _has_ declared the `medList` member as a pointer.  That was _probably_ unnecessary, but depends on the implementation of `DynamicVector`.

Comment: DynamicVector<Medicine>* MedList; // in repository.h

this->MedList = new DynamicVector<Medicine>(); // in repository.cpp it's not working. The error:undefined reference to `DynamicVector<Medicine>::DynamicVector()'

Comment: You have some other problems not shown by the code examples provided (like missing include directives).  Can you update your question with your actual code?

Comment: @CucerzanRares: As per your latest error: could you post the class definition of `DynamicVector` as well (i.e. not only the constructor). Is the constructor declared public?

Comment: @TomasLycken I updated the code. Yes, the constructor is public

Comment: @CucerzanRares: I tried to reproduce the error, but my code compiles fine: http://pastebin.com/Bd1byiND (I compile it by saving it in scratch.cpp and running `make scratch.o`)

Answer (score 0):

Constructor should be:

```
Repository::Repository(){
    this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>;
}
```

DynamicVector() calls the constructor for DynamicVector.

DynamicVector::DynamicVector() is a pointer to the **address** of the constructor function

Comment: it's not working either. Thanks! This is the error now: Multiple markers at this line
 - candidate is:
 - no match for 'operator=' in '((Repository*)this)->Repository::MedList = (operator new(12u), (<statement>, 
  ((DynamicVector<Medicine>*)<anonymous>)))'

Comment: No, error: undefined reference to `DynamicVector<Medicine>::DynamicVector()'

Comment: You shouldn't be getting an undefined reference unless you put the definition of the DynamicVector constructor in a separate file. If the definition of the constructor is in the same header file that contains the DynamicVector class template and you're still getting an undefined reference error, I'm sorry but don't know what's wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

The chances are your C++ version doesn't allow empty () for constructors.

```
this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>::DynamicVector(); //error
```

should be

```
this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>::DynamicVector;
```

or (The usual way of writing it)

```
this->MedList=new DynamicVector<Medicine>;
```

See here for more info.

**EDIT. Make sure you have declared the dynamicVector constructor in the class.**

---

[Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets)

[Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)