# What is the difference between Object b(); and Object b;?

Tags: c++, class, instance-variables, default-constructor

To be more explicit, I get a compile time error when I try accessing an instance variable when I create an object using (), but when I don't, the code compiles and runs as expected.  Also, this problem only applies to the default constructor.
I would like to understand why.

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Student {

  public:

    int gpa;

    Student() { 
      gpa = 4;
    }

    Student( int x ) { 
      gpa = x; 
    }

};

int main() {

  Student zero;
  Student sally( 2 ); 
  Student jack();

  cout << zero.gpa << endl; //prints 4
  cout << sally.gpa << endl; // prints 2
  cout << jack.gpa << endl; //error: request for member 'gpa' in 'jack', which is of non-class type 'Student()'

}
```

Comment: Why dont you use new?

Comment: This is not an issue of trying to get around the problem.  I want to understand why I run into the error in the first place.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Why should he? Automatic lifetime beats dynamic lifetime whenever it is applicable.

Comment: This has been answered here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets

Comment: @delnan, you mean it gets auto deleted when out of scope? Just like a simple float var; ?

Comment: Yes. Using `new` allocates the memory on the heap rather than on the stack, which means that it has to be explicitly deleted later on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `Student jack();` declares a function with `Student` as a return type. It doesn't declare an object of that class as you expect.

Comment: ohhh! That's so subtle.  I thought it had something to with that, but wasn't sure.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
  Student jack();
```

declares a function that returns student and takes no arguments. Not an object!

See more in this [gotw](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/06/gotw-1-variable-initialization-or-is-it-310/)

Answer (score 3):

"Object b();" declares a function b() returning an object of type Object, while "Object b;" defines a variable b of type Object.

No, it's not obvious, and it still comes back to bite me if I switch between C++, Java, and C#.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between Object b(); and Object b;?

The difference exists because C++ interprets that as a function being declared, instead of an object being created.

```
Object b;
```

This is the object `b` of class `Object` being created by means of the default constructor.

```
Object b();
```

This is the function `b()`, being declared (it will be defined elsewhere) to return an object of class `Object`, and no parameters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this

class Student {

public:

```
int gpa = 4;

Student() { };
```